# How to use putExtra() and getExtra() for string data

Tags: android, android-intent

Can someone please tell me how exactly to use `getExtra()` and `putExtra()` for intents? Actually I have a string variable, say str, which stores some string data. Now, I want to send this data from one activity to another activity.

```
  Intent i = new Intent(FirstScreen.this, SecondScreen.class);   
  String keyIdentifer  = null;
  i.putExtra(strName, keyIdentifer );
```

and then in the SecondScreen.java

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.table);
        TextView userName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.userName);
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

        if(bundle.getString("strName")!= null)
        {
            //TODO here get the string stored in the string variable and do 
            // setText() on userName 
        }

    }
```

I know it is very basic question but unfortunately I am stuck here. 
Please help.

Thanks,

Edit: Here the string which I am trying to pass from one screen to the other is dynamic.
That is I have an editText where I am getting string whatever user types. Then with the help of `myEditText.getText().toString()` . I am getting the entered value as a string then I have to pass this data.

Comment: i.putExtra(strName, keyIdentifer );
This statement has strName variable while bundle.getString("strName") has "strName" String.

Its 
intent.putExtra(key, value)
and intent.getExtras().getString(key);

make sure you are using same key in put and get.

Answer (score 459, accepted):

Use this to "put" the file...

```
Intent i = new Intent(FirstScreen.this, SecondScreen.class);   
String strName = null;
i.putExtra("STRING_I_NEED", strName);
```

Then, to retrieve the value try something like:

```
String newString;
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(extras == null) {
        newString= null;
    } else {
        newString= extras.getString("STRING_I_NEED");
    }
} else {
    newString= (String) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("STRING_I_NEED");
}
```

Comment: is the "savedInstanceState..." and "...getSerialiable" code used to handle orientation changes?  if no, what is that code used for?

Comment: I'm using android 3.0.1 and I had to use `this.getActivity().getIntent().getExtras()`.

Comment: If you use PendingIntents, you need to use the "PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT" flag:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/29846408/2738240

Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("button_id", 1);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.my_test_widget);
            views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.my_test_widget_button_1, pendingIntent);

Answer (score 80):

**first Screen.java**

```
text=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv1);
edit=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit);
button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bt1);

button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        String s=edit.getText().toString();

        Intent ii=new Intent(MainActivity.this, newclass.class);
        ii.putExtra("name", s);
        startActivity(ii);
    }
});
```

**Second Screen.java**

```
public class newclass extends Activity
{
    private TextView Textv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.intent);
        Textv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv2);
        Intent iin= getIntent();
        Bundle b = iin.getExtras();

        if(b!=null)
        {
            String j =(String) b.get("name");
            Textv.setText(j);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 56):

Best Method...

SendingActivity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(SendingActivity.this, RecievingActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("keyName", value);  // pass your values and retrieve them in the other Activity using keyName
startActivity(intent);
```

RecievingActivity

```
 Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    if(extras != null)
    String data = extras.getString("keyName"); // retrieve the data using keyName
```

/// shortest way to recieve data..

```
String data = getIntent().getExtras().getString("keyName","defaultKey");
```

//This requires api 12.
            //the second parameter is optional . If keyName is null then use the `defaultkey` as data.

Answer (score 24):

This is what i have been using, hopfully it helps someone.. simple and affective.

send data

```
    intent = new Intent(getActivity(), CheckinActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("mealID", meal.Meald);
    startActivity(intent);
```

get data

```
    int mealId;

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

    if(bundle != null){
        mealId = bundle.getInt("mealID");
    }
```

cheers!

Comment: I still have to remind my self, now and then, how this was done properly.. lol!

Answer (score 10):

It is very easy to implement `intent` in Android.. It takes you to move from one activity to another activity,we have to two method `putExtra();` and `getExtra();`Now I am showing you the example..

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(activity_registration.this, activity_Login.class);
                intent.putExtra("AnyKeyName", Email.getText().toString());  // pass your values and retrieve them in the other Activity using AnyKeyName
                        startActivity(intent);
```

Now we have to get the value from `AnyKeyName` parameter,the below mentioned code will help in doing this

```
       String data = getIntent().getExtras().getString("AnyKeyName");
        textview.setText(data);
```

We can easily set the receiving value from `Intent`,wherever we required.

Answer (score 7):

A small addendum: you do not have to create your own name for the key, android provides these, f.ex. [`Intent.EXTRA_TEXT`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#EXTRA_TEXT). Modifying the accepted answer:

> ```
> Intent i = new Intent(FirstScreen.this, SecondScreen.class);   
> String strName = null;
> i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, strName);
> ```
>
> Then, to retrieve the value try something like:
>
> ```
> String newString;
> Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
> if(extras == null) {
>     newString= null;
> } else {
>     newString= extras.getString(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
> }
> ```

Answer (score 6):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), ApplicationActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("int", intValue);
                        intent.putExtra("Serializable", object);
                        intent.putExtra("String", stringValue);
                        intent.putExtra("parcelable", parObject);
                        startActivity(intent);
```

ApplicationActivity

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

if(bundle != null){
   int mealId = bundle.getInt("int");
   Object object = bundle.getSerializable("Serializable");
   String string = bundle.getString("String");
   T string = <T>bundle.getString("parcelable");
}
```

Answer (score 6):

send

```
startActivity(new Intent(First.this, Secend.class).putExtra("key",edit.getText.tostring));
```

get

```
String myData = getIntent.getStringExtra("key");
```

Answer (score 5):

#### Update in [Intent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent) class.

- Use `hasExtra()` for checking if intent has data on key.
- You can use now `getStringExtra()` directly.

**Pass Data**

```
intent.putExtra(PutExtraConstants.USER_NAME, "user");
```

**Get Data**

```
String userName;
if (getIntent().hasExtra(PutExtraConstants.USER_NAME)) {
    userName = getIntent().getStringExtra(PutExtraConstants.USER_NAME);
}
```

**Always put keys in constants as best practice.**

```
public interface PutExtraConstants {
    String USER_NAME = "USER_NAME";
}
```

Comment: Why is `PutExtraConstants` an interface?

Comment: @Big_Chair Because `PutExtraConstants` class contains only constants (`public`, `static`, `final`). So it is better to use interface for Constants.

Answer (score 4):

More simple

sender side

```
Intent i = new Intent(SourceActiviti.this,TargetActivity.class);
i.putExtra("id","string data");
startActivity(i)
```

receiver side

```
Intent i = new Intent(SourceActiviti.this,TargetActivity.class);
String strData = i.getStringExtra("id");
```

Comment: I will always vote for simplicity especially where code does same thing.

Answer (score 4):

Put String in Intent Object

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this,NextAcitivity.class);
  intent.putExtra("key",your_String);
  StartActivity(intent);
```

NextAcitvity in onCreate method get String

```
String my_string=getIntent().getStringExtra("key");
```

that is easy and short method

Answer (score 2):

**At FirstScreen.java**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(FirstScreen.this, SecondScreen.class);
String keyIdentifier = null;
intent.putExtra(strName, keyIdentifier);
```

**At SecondScreen.java**

```
String keyIdentifier;
if (savedInstanceState != null)
    keyIdentifier= (String) savedInstanceState.getSerializable(strName);
else
    keyIdentifier = getIntent().getExtras().getString(strName);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please edit your answer and elaborate a bit why and how it solves the issue. For more guidance, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 1):

**Push Data**

```
import android.content.Intent;

    ...

    Intent intent = 
        new Intent( 
            this, 
            MyActivity.class );
    intent.putExtra( "paramName", "paramValue" );
    startActivity( intent );
```

The above code might be inside the main `activity`. "`MyActivity.class`" is the second `Activity` we want to launch; it must be explicitly included in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity" />
```

**Pull Data**

```
import android.os.Bundle;

    ...

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null)
    {
        String myParam = extras.getString("paramName");
    }
    else
    {
        //..oops!
    }
```

In this example, the above code would be inside your `MyActivity.java` file.

Gotchas

This method can only pass `strings`. So let's say you need to pass an `ArrayList` to your `ListActivity`; a possible workaround is to pass a comma-separated-string and then split it on the other side.

Alternative Solutions

Use `SharedPreferences`

Comment: and what if I want to pass a string from string.xml?

Answer (score 1):

put function

```
etname=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.Name);
        tvname=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvName);

        b1= (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Submit);

        b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                String s=etname.getText().toString();

                Intent ii=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity2.class);
                ii.putExtra("name", s);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Page 222", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                startActivity(ii);
            }
        });



getfunction 

public class MainActivity2 extends Activity {
    TextView tvname;
    EditText etname;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity2);
        tvname = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvName);
        etname=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.Name);
        Intent iin= getIntent();
        Bundle b = iin.getExtras();

        if(b!=null)
        {

          String j2 =(String) b.get("name");

etname.setText(j2);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"ok",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple,
In first Activity-

```
    EditText name= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
    Button button= (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonGo);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class);
            i.putExtra("name",name.getText().toString());
           startActivity(i);
          }
    });
```

In second Activity-

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    Bundle bundle=getIntent().getExtras();
    String s=bundle.getString("name");
    t.setText(s);
}
```

> You can add if/else conditions if you want.

Answer (score 0):

put string first

```
Intent secondIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(SecondActivity));
            secondIntent.PutExtra("message", "Greetings from MainActivity");
```

retrieve it after that

```
var message = this.Intent.GetStringExtra("message");
```

thats All ;)

Answer (score 0):

A single inlined code would be enough for this task. This worked for me effortlessly.
For #android devlopers out there.
`String strValue=Objects.requireNonNull(getIntent().getExtras()).getString("string_Key");`

Answer (score -2):

You can Simply use static variable to store the string of your edittext and then use that variable in the other class. Hope this will solve your problem

Comment: You _can_ but you shouldn't :-)