# how to use edittext in numberpicker?

Tags: java, android, textview, android-edittext

am working in android. Am using `NumberPicker` which i got from [here](http://www.technologichron.net/) i want the input value taken from the `NumberPicker` should be displayed in the `TextView` which i have written in different `class`.. how can i do this.. please help.. here is a code..

```
public class home_try extends Activity {

private NumberPicker numberpicker;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.dummy1);
final Dialog textDialog = new Dialog(this); 
Button setpoint= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
setpoint.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {
textDialog.getWindow().setFlags( 
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND, 
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND); 
textDialog.getWindow().setLayout(300, 200); 
textDialog.setTitle("Set Temperature"); 

LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
View myView = li.inflate(R.layout.main, null); 
textDialog.setContentView(myView); 
textDialog.show(); 
        }
    });
Button set=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
set.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {
setContentView(R.layout.dummy1);
}
});
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you've used the widget right....

```
NumberPicker numPicker = (NumberPicker)findViewById(R.id.whatever);
int value = numPicker.getValue();
tvTextView.setText(String.valueOf(value));
```

Comment: no i dint use the widget... but i used this link http://www.technologichron.net/ for numberpicker..

Comment: @user976538, I'm talking about the same widget they provided.

Answer (score 0):

pass the value along intetnt using putExtra and by getting it in next class(Activity) you can set that value using setText() method......

Comment: where should i use the intent? is it in numberpicker.java class?

Comment: As far as i'm getting from your question you have used number picker in one activity and you want to display the value selected by user in next activity. so you must be jumping from the activity where you have used number picker for user to select a value to the activity where you want to display that selection. so for jumping from first activity(where number picker implemented) to 2nd activity (where you have used TextView to display selected value) you must be using intent.

Comment: along this intent use putExtra to pass value and by getting that value in 2nd activity you can set it to TextView using setText() Method.

Comment: For using putExtra you can get help from answer of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265913/how-to-use-putextra-and-getextra-for-string-data

Answer (score 0):

The android's numberpicker is a custom view that contains two buttons and a textview.
If you can put a complete control on the numberpicker, you can make your own custom numberpicker view, and add a getter method that returns its textbox, or, text of the textbox. you can download the android source code for number picker from [here](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android/App/gasmixer/divestoclimb/scuba/equipment/widget/NumberPicker.java.htm). do not forget to add numberpicker layout xml file from [here](http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/source/browse/android/AndroidScriptingEnvironment/res/layout/number_picker.xml?r=6dea61dc32e55c766868b93a76ba5531119df99e).