# How to send text in clipboard to EditText box

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-edittext, android-activity

My app with two activities is targeted to run on Android 4 or above. **Activity 1** displays a Webview, and **Activity 2** consists of a Listview and an EditText.

I would like to programmatically send/export any text copied in the Webview of **Activity 1** to the EditText of **Activity 2** once a button is pressed.

To make it clear, my purpose is to create a button to listen to any text copied to clipboard. When the button is pressed, Activity 2 will be called and the text in clipboard will be sent/pasted to the EditText (edtbox) of Activity 2

So far, I have applied the following code lines:

Activity 1 (on button clicked):

```
ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE); 
clipboard.setText("Text to copy");
clipboard.getText();

Intent i = new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class);
Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
bundle.putString("clipboard", "Android");
i.putExtras(bundle);   
startActivity(i);
```

Activity 2 (under onCreate):

```
Bundle bundle=getIntent().getExtras();
if(bundle !=null)
{
    String name=bundle.getString("clipboard");
    EditText edttxt=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtbox);
    edttxt.setText(name);
}
```

However, Activity 2 fails to be loaded and Eclipse throws a crash. I guess I haven't sent clipboard text to EditText of Activity 2 but don't know how to do.

I wonder whether you guys can help me to solve this problem. Thank you very much in advance.

=====

**UPDATED:**

Here is the [Eclipse LogCat](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/15034088/Others/Temps/logcat.rtf):

Comment: Could you copy the error output by logcat?

Comment: Use this example
[How to get Extras][1]
it is much clear


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265913/how-to-use-putextra-and-getextra-for-string-data

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why can't you use like this....

```
 ====>At Activity 1

 Intent i = new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class);
 //Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
 //bundle.putString("clipboard", "Android");
  i.putExtras("clipboard", "Android");
  startActivity(i);


 ====>At Activity 2
EditText edttxt=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtbox);//place edit text declaration out side of the Bundle Extras block
Bundle bundle=getIntent().getExtras();
if(bundle !=null)
{
  String name=bundle.getString("clipboard");
  edttxt.setText(name);
}
```

Comment: @Ramkiran-I think your activity 2 will cause Error as they are not sent via bundle..

Answer (score 1):

Try this one::

**Activity 1 (on button clicked):**

```
ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE); 
clipboard.setText("Text to copy");
Sting cpytext = clipboard.getText();

Intent i = new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class);
//Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
//bundle.putString("clipboard", cpytext);
i.putExtra("clipboard", cpytext);   
startActivity(i);
```

**Activity 2 (under onCreate):**

```
if(getIntent().hasExtra("clipboard")) {
     String name = (getIntent().getStringExtra("clipboard"));
     EditText edttxt=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtbox);
     edttxt.setText(name);
}
```

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233873/how-to-get-extra-data-from-intent-in-android

Comment: @Ramkiran-Yes that is true..but using String is more efficient.

Comment: @NilayOnAndroid: Thanks a lot but Eclipse still throws NullPointerException. When `i.putExtra("clipboard", cpytext);` is removed, Activity 2 is successfully called but of course there no text in EditText.

Comment: @NiamhDoyle-It shows NullPointer Exception because it is not getting value of cpytext at the time of "i.putExtra("clipboard", cpytext);"

Comment: So u should debug it and check why this error. Use try/catch for that.