# Taken value from edittext and passing it as a string to another activity

Tags: android, eclipse, string, android-intent, android-activity

Im looking to take the value from a `edittext` field and pass it to another activity as a string. I have done below as shown. I think its working but I would like be to able to print the text out to see if the variable value actually passed over

But once I type `Log.d("PJM",value);` the activty closes with a error

MainScreen Activity

```
public class MainScreen extends Activity {

Button btnSearch, btnFavourites;
EditText enterDefinition;
Editable word;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_screen);

    btnSearch=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSearch);
    btnFavourites=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnFavourites);
    enterDefinition=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.enterDefinition);

    String text = enterDefinition.getText().toString();

    Intent i = new Intent(this, Definition.class);
    i.putExtra("KEY",text);
    //startActivity(i);

    //Intent i = new Intent(this, Definition.class);
    //i.putExtra("text_Label",theText);
    //startActivity(i);
```

Definition Activity

```
public class Definition extends Activity {

Button btnSend, btnSaveFave, btnReturn;
EditText enterDefinition;
String value;
TextView definition;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_definition);

    btnSend=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSend);
    btnSaveFave=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSaveFave);
    btnReturn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnReturn);
    enterDefinition=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.enterDefinition);
    definition=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvDefinition);

    definition.setText("some text");

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    String value = null; 
    if (extras != null) {
      value = extras.getString("KEY");
    }
    else {
      value = "None";
    }
    Log.d("text entered", value);
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), value, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265913/how-to-use-putextra-and-getextra-for-string-data this will help

Comment: Have you declared Definition.class in your Manifest??

Comment: yes it is declared in the manifest, everytime I run it, it comes out as none in the logcat

Comment: I'm assuming you've commented out startActivity(i) by mistake?

Comment: no becuase if i uncomment it, it just starts the 'definition activity' straight away without giving me a chance to type into the 'editText' in the 'mainscreen'

Answer (score 1):

You want:

```
String value = null; 
if (extras != null) {
  value = extras.getString("KEY");
}
else {
  value = "None"
}
Log.d("PJM", value);
```

Comment: Ok, well there is a problem with the Bundle then. Can you post the full code? Are you definitely calling startActivity(i, <requestCode>) in the first activity?

Comment: Actually, even better. Run in debug mode, put a breakpoint at the if statement in the second activity, and check the content of extras by hovering the mouse pointer over variable.

Comment: Look at the code I edited in my first question, I am not starting the activity as it just means once i start my app it runs straight into the definition activity. should i put the code to pass the intent into the onClickListener for running that activity?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was thinking. So where in the process is this Intent i used? In the code you posted, it is completely redundant. Certainly, if you have an listener for a button click that then starts the Definitions activity, then you have to put the intent in its onClick method, and call startActivity(i) from within there.

Comment: ie onClick (View v) { Intent i = new Intent(this, Definition.class); i.putExtra("KEY",text); startActivity(i); } This way the intent is sent with Bundle data.

Comment: I get the error 'The constructor Intent(new View.OnClickListener(){}, Class<Definition>) is undefined' when i create the intent.

Comment: Use getBaseContext() as your Context for the first argument. Actually,  post the code for the OnClickListener to be sure you are setting it up correctly.