# How to send a phone number between activities?

Tags: android, service, android-activity, uri

I have an EditView where the user is supposed to input a phone number. I then want to take that phone number and call/text it in another activity. How could I do that?

This is part of my Main Activity:

```
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    editText.setOnClickListener(this);

  }
public void onClick(View src) {
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
     switch (src.getId()) {
            case R.id.button1:
              Log.d(TAG, "onClick: starting service");
              EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
              if (editText.getText().toString()==""){
                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter a  phone number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              } else {
                  pnumber = editText.getText().toString();
                  startService(serviceIntent);  
                  serviceIntent.putExtra(number, pnumber);

              break;
              }

            }
          }

        }
```

And then in my other Activity:

```
    Bundle extras = this.getIntent().getExtras(); {
    if(extras !=null)
{
    String newnumber = extras.getString(number,pnumber);
    Uri number = Uri.parse(newnumber);
    Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, number);
    Intent textIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, number);
}
}

public void onClick(View view) {

    switch (view.getId()) {
    case R.id.button2:
      //Log.d(TAG, "onClick: starting call");
      startActivity(callIntent);
      break;
    case R.id.button3:
        //Log.d(TAG, "onClick: start text message");
        startActivity(textIntent);
        break;
        }       
        }
     }
```

The Uri keeps parsing "newnumber" and giving a phone number made from the numbers that have those letters (For example, I would get 639686237 since n is on the 6 key, e is on the 3 key etc.) It also doesn't recognize the variables number and pnumber.

Comment: Call `startService()` **after** `putExtra()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send your data in two activities like that:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, MyService.class);
intent.putExtra("number", pnumber);
startActivity(intent);
```

And you can get this value in MyService.class:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String yourNumber = intent.getStringExtra("number");
```

---

Or your can put your values in bundle:

In your current activity:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("number", pnumber);
bundle.putStirng("name", "yourNameValue");
bundle.putInt("age", "ageValue");
Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, MyService.class);
intent.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(intent);
```

And in your MyService activity:

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
String number = bundle.getString("number");
String name = bundle.getString("name");
int age = bundle.getInt("age");
```

I hope that helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Due to **intent.putExtra(String name, Bundle extra)** statement in first activity, to get the **pnumber** in second activity we requires the string **name**. There is no scope of **number** (**name** in your case) and **pnumber** variables in the second class.

So instantiate a variable having the value of number in the second class **ValueOfNumber**, this will serve as the key to get **pnumber** from the intent.

Use

```
pnumber=extras.getString(ValueOfNumber); //ValueOfNumber is the value of number variable in first activity.
```

Also call startService after Intent.putExtras.

Refer to [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265913/how-to-use-putextra-and-getextra-for-string-data)

Answer (score -1):

Used SharedPreferences. There'a nice thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values) for it. With it, you can save the number in a Preference file (visible only for the current application and not in the file system). Like this one:

```
private final String PREFS_NAME  = "savefile";
private final String KEY_NUMBER    = "num";
String strWithTheNumber = "00 123 456 789"
String strSavedValue = "";
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = ctx.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

*//To put the phone in the file*

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
editor.putString(KEY_NUMBER, strWithTheNumber);
editor.commit();
```

*//To retrieve the number*

```
strSavedValue = sharedPreferences.getString("num", null);
```