# Android - Export Option on ListAdapter to another Activity which has EditText

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, listadapter

So I have a `ListAdapter` which has various options and what I want is that when a user clicks on the `ListAdapter` an activity starts which has an `EditText` and the `EditText` should be automatically filled with option which was, clicked on for the `ListAdapter`.

Currently I have Main.java:

```
public class Main extends ListActivity{
    String options[] = {"option1","option2"};
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>   (Main.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,options);
    }

    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l,View v, int position, long id){
       super.onListItemClick(l,v,position,id);
       try{
       Class theClass = Class.forname("com.example.SecondActivity");
       Intent oI = new Intent(Main.this,theClass);
       startActivity(oI);
       }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){e.printStackTrace();}
    }
```

SecondActivity.java (This contains the activity with the edit text):

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity{
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContextView(R.layout.secondactivity)
      EditText edt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt1);
    }
```

What all extra do I need to do so that this works. All the help is deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

While starting an activity, you can send more information to that activity like an integer or String value. It can be send in the following way:

```
Intent addIntent = new Intent();
addIntent.putExtra(String name, String value).
```

So, you can send the name to your new activity. Then you need to get this value in onCreate function using **getExtra()** function. and can use to fill the editText.

Below link will give you more insight:

[How to use putExtra() and getExtra() for string data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265913/how-to-use-putextra-and-getextra-for-string-data)

Comment: I tried doing that, but I can't achieve any result.

Comment: could you please explain in which particular place you faced issue?

Comment: What I don't get it is how will the EditText know which position on the ListAdapter has been clicked ?

Comment: In onListItemClick, one of the paramemter is the "position". You can even pass this information to your new activity.

Comment: Thats exactly what I did, but then the application crashes.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l,View v, int position, long id){
   super.onListItemClick(l,v,position,id);
   try{
   Class theClass = Class.forname("com.example.SecondActivity");
   Intent oI = new Intent(Main.this,theClass);

   oI.putExtra("selectedText", options[position]);

   startActivity(oI);
   }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){e.printStackTrace();}
}


public class SecondActivity extends Activity{
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContextView(R.layout.secondactivity)

  EditText edt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt1);
   if(getIntent()!=null && getIntent().getExtras()!=null)
    {
        String value = getIntent().getStringExtra("selectedText");
        edt.setText(value);
    }
}
```

let me know if it works ok, I haven't tested it.

Comment: I tried this but it throws and error and my application crashes.

Comment: I've made some changes, if you haven't yet solved the problem please try again.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem by making use of putExtra instead of getExtras