# Passing data through two activities?

Tags: java, android

For an app I am developing, I am having the user input some information on one activity, and then on the next, the user will read something, in such that he/she won't be putting any information on it, but on the third activity, I want to display what the user put in the first. Is there a way I can carry that information from the 1st to the 3rd activity without going through the second?

Comment: You didn't google it well. See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265913/how-to-use-putextra-and-getextra-for-string-data

Comment: You can use putExtra() to send something and getExtra to receive from another activity

Comment: Thank you everyone for your answers. I will try them all out! Thank you all again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use sharedPreferences to store that piece of data on the phone. On the 3rd activity, read it and use it.
See it here-
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

Answer (score 0):

***This can be done in many ways !***

**Why not use Intents to pass the data ?**

---

**STEP-1**: <***Eg:: From Activity1***>

Pass the `telefone`  into a new activity with the help of intents

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Activity2.class);
i.putExtra("title",telefone);
i.putExtra("descrip",telefone);
startActivity(i);
```

---

**STEP-2**: <***Eg:: From Activity2***>

Receive the string passed in another activity

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    String title= extras.getString("title");
    String descrip= extras.getString("descrip");
}
```

---

**STEP-3**: <***Eg:: From Activity2***> ***pass data again to Activity3***

*Receive the string passed in another activity*

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    String title= extras.getString("title");
    String descrip= extras.getString("descrip");
}
```

*Pass the data to Activity3*

```
 Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Activity3.class);
    i.putExtra("title",telefone);
    i.putExtra("descrip",telefone);
    startActivity(i);
```

---

***Hope it helps ! ..........Let me know if you need more info***

Answer (score 0):

Use SharedPreference. Save in A1 and retrieve in A3.

**Initialization**

```
SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0); // 0 - for private mode
Editor editor = pref.edit();
```

**Storing Data**

```
editor.putBoolean("key_name", true); // Storing boolean - true/false
editor.putString("key_name", "string value"); // Storing string
editor.putInt("key_name", "int value"); // Storing integer
editor.putFloat("key_name", "float value"); // Storing float
editor.putLong("key_name", "long value"); // Storing long

editor.commit(); // commit changes
```

**Retrieving Data**

```
// returns stored preference value
// If value is not present return second param value - In this case null
pref.getString("key_name", null); // getting String
pref.getInt("key_name", null); // getting Integer
pref.getFloat("key_name", null); // getting Float
pref.getLong("key_name", null); // getting Long
pref.getBoolean("key_name", null); // getting boolean
```

**Deleting Data**

```
editor.remove("name"); // will delete key name
editor.remove("email"); // will delete key email
editor.commit(); // commit changes
```

**Clearing Storage**

```
editor.clear();
editor.commit(); // commit changes
```