# Passing a Variable to new class in Android

Tags: java, android

Good morning folks (GMT)

I'm still learning Java, and Android development, I know this may be a simple question, but it's been driving me crazy for a while. I've searched Google and here and couldn't find the answer.

I have a variable `listViewId`, it's in my `Offers` class, its current value is `null`

Later in the code, Once a button is pressed from a `ListView`, the Variable is initialized with the ID of the `ListView`, This works fine however, and opens my new `Activity` page.

The issue i'm having, I need the `listViewId` variable to then Toast in the New Description Page.

I've tried the offers.var Code with no luck, I've even tried a `Helper` class, but when the variable is Toasted it is the `null` Value and not the value of the `listViewID`

Kind Regards

```
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.offers_layout, menu);

      eventslist.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            listviewIDEvents = (int) id; // takes listview ID from button pushed and stores the value to the variable listViewIDEvents
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(events.this, description.class);
            myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
            events.this.startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    });
```

---

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.eventspage);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_NOSENSOR);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Welcome to the Description page " , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: Food for the thought: Try searching around `Intent` and passing values between activities.

Comment: can you post some code

Comment: sure, Edited post its in there now :)

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by *I need the listViewId variable to then Toast in the New Description Page.* Don't you basically just want to send it over in an `Intent Extra`?

Comment: I have a null Variable. ListViewIdEvents. its an INT 

once a button is pushed in a listview, the variable ListViewIDEvents, the value is then changed to the element ID 

For Example, if Element 5 is pushed the Variable ListViewIDEvents will have the value of 5, I need this value, To be displayed in another Activity on a toast!

Comment: based on the accepted answer, you did want to send it over as an intent extra :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to pass date to your activity class, you can use intent.putExtra() to send data to another activity here is the [example](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidIntent/article.html) also you can find similar solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265913/how-to-use-putextra-and-getextra-for-string-data)

```
 myIntent.putExtra("ID", listviewIDEvents);
```

and in activity you can do is :

```
 id= getIntent().getExtras().getString("ID");
```

also you can send integer too, hope it helps

Comment: i am glad it helped :), accept the answer please if it does so that others can use it too and happy coding :)