# get extra data android, keep force close apps

Tags: android, android-intent

here is how i sent extra data

```
btn_category.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    WriteLog.d("ThangTB", "onclick image");
                    Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,QuoteList.class);
                    i.putExtra("category", "ok");
                    MainActivity.this.startActivity(i);
                }
            });
```

and receive data using

```
Intent intent = getIntent();

    //ambil data putextra variabel category dari intent     
    String category = intent.getStringExtra("category");
    //if category sama dengan ok
    if(category=="ok")
        spinnerCategory.performClick();
```

it's keep force close when click the button.
i've try [How to use putExtra() and getExtra() for string data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265913/how-to-use-putextra-and-getextra-for-string-data), but still force close when i click the button

here is complete code of QuoteList

```
/**
```

* 
 */
public class QuoteList extends AbstractContentActivity {

```
Spinner spinnerPage;
Spinner spinnerCategory;
ListView lv;

ImageButton btn_expand;
ImageButton btn_logo;
Button btn_next;
Button btn_pre;

TextView tv_empty;
QuoteAdapter adapter;
DataHeper dataHeper;
ArrayList<Quote> listData;
private ProgressDialog dialogLoading;

private boolean isSort = false;
private int iStart =0;
int total;
ArrayList<String> listSpinerPage;
ArrayList<String> listSpinerCategory;

private int currentPostion =0;
private boolean hasGetTotal = false;
private boolean firstStart = true; 
/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see com.android.jokesapp.jokes2.activity.AbstractActivity#getViewLayoutId()
 */
@Override
protected int getViewLayoutId() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return R.layout.full_quotes_index;
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see com.android.jokesapp.jokes2.activity.AbstractContentActivity#initView()
 */
@Override
protected void initView() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.initView();
    spinnerPage = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.fqi_page_no);
    spinnerCategory = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.fqi_category);
    lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.fqi_ListView);
    btn_expand = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.fqi_expand_quotes_btn);
    btn_logo = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.actionbar_logo_btn);
    btn_next = (Button)findViewById(R.id.fqi_next_btn);
    btn_pre = (Button)findViewById(R.id.fqi_previous_btn);

    tv_empty = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.empty);

    SplashActivity.displayBanner(this);

    dataHeper = new DataHeper(getApplicationContext());
    listData = new ArrayList<Quote>();
    listSpinerPage = new ArrayList<String>();
    listSpinerCategory = new ArrayList<String>();


    Intent intent = getIntent();

    //ambil data putextra variabel category dari intent     
    String category = intent.getStringExtra("category");
    //if category sama dengan ok
    if(category=="ok")
        spinnerCategory.performClick();

    //spinnercategory performclick






    btn_expand.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (adapter.isExpand()) {
                adapter.setExpand(false);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                btn_expand.setImageResource(R.drawable.actionbar_ic_resize);
                btn_expand.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
            }else{
                adapter.setExpand(true);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                btn_expand.setImageResource(R.drawable.actionbar_ic_resize_pressed);
                btn_expand.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
            }
        }
    });

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int pos,
                long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), QuoteView.class);
            i.putExtra(Constants.Bundle_quote, listData.get(pos));
            currentPostion = pos;
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    btn_logo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            QuoteList.this.finish();
        }
    });

}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see com.android.jokesapp.jokes2.activity.AbstractActivity#onResume()
 */
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    new GetData().execute();
    super.onResume();
}
/**
 * get data task
 * @author ThangTB
 *
 */
private class GetData extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object>{

    public GetData() {
    }
    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.os.AsyncTask#onPreExecute()
     */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialogLoading = DialogLoading.Loading(activity,"Loading jokes...");
        dialogLoading.show();
    }
    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.os.AsyncTask#doInBackground(Params[])
     */
    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (!hasGetTotal) {
            total = dataHeper.getTotalQuotesNoFilter();
            if (total>0) {
                if (total>=50) {
                    for (int i = 1; i <= total-50; i+=50) {
                        String s = (i)+" - "+ (i+49);
                        listSpinerPage.add(s);
                    }

                    String s1 = listSpinerPage.get(listSpinerPage.size()-1);
                    String s2 = s1.substring(s1.indexOf("-")+1); 
                    int num =Integer.parseInt(s2.trim());
                    if ( num<total) {
                        listSpinerPage.add((num)+" - "+ total);
                    }
                }else{
                    listSpinerPage.add(1+" - "+ total);
                }

            }
            hasGetTotal = true;
        }

        return null;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.os.AsyncTask#onPostExecute(java.lang.Object)
     */
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
        if (total>0) {
            new GetQuoteData(iStart, null,"").execute();
            if (firstStart) {
                tv_empty.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                //list
                CustomArrayAdapter spinnerAdapter = new CustomArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(), 
                        R.layout.spinner_item_style, 
                        listSpinerPage);
                spinnerPage.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
                spinnerPage.setOnItemSelectedListener(onItemSelectedListener);
                //category
                listSpinerCategory = dataHeper.getCategory();
                CustomArrayAdapter catAdapter = new CustomArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                        R.layout.spinner_item_style,
                        listSpinerCategory);
                spinnerCategory.setAdapter(catAdapter);
                spinnerCategory.setOnItemSelectedListener(selectCategory);
            }

        }else{
            tv_empty.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            dialogLoading.dismiss();
        }

        firstStart = false;
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
}

OnItemSelectedListener selectCategory =new OnItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int pos,
            long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String category = listSpinerCategory.get(pos);
        String sStart = listSpinerPage.get(pos);
        iStart = Integer.parseInt(sStart.substring(0, sStart.indexOf("-")-1).trim());
        new GetQuoteData(iStart, null, category).execute();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
};


OnItemSelectedListener onItemSelectedListener =new OnItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int pos,
            long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String sStart = listSpinerPage.get(pos);
        iStart = Integer.parseInt(sStart.substring(0, sStart.indexOf("-")-1).trim());
        new GetQuoteData(iStart, null, "").execute();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
};

OnItemSelectedListener onSpinnerSortItemSelectedListener =new OnItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int pos,
            long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String sStart;
        if (!isSort) {
            isSort =true;
            return;
        }else{
            sStart = listSpinerPage.get(spinnerPage.getSelectedItemPosition());
            iStart = Integer.parseInt(sStart.substring(0, sStart.indexOf("-")-1).trim());
            new GetQuoteData(iStart, null, "").execute();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

    }
};

/**
 * get data task
 * @author ThangTB
 *
 */
private class GetQuoteData extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object>{
    private int start;
    private String sort;
    private String category = "";
    public GetQuoteData(int start, String sort, String category) {
        this.start = start;
        this.sort = sort;
        this.category = category;
    }
    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.os.AsyncTask#onPreExecute()
     */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        if (null == dialogLoading) {
            dialogLoading = DialogLoading.Loading(activity,"Loading jokes...");
            dialogLoading.show();
        }else if (!dialogLoading.isShowing()) {
            dialogLoading = DialogLoading.Loading(activity,"Loading jokes...");
            dialogLoading.show();
        }

    }
    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.os.AsyncTask#doInBackground(Params[])
     */
    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (category.isEmpty()) listData = dataHeper.getQuoteByLimit(start, 50, sort);
        else listData = dataHeper.getQuoteByCategory(category);
        return null;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.os.AsyncTask#onPostExecute(java.lang.Object)
     */
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {

        adapter = new QuoteAdapter(getApplicationContext(), listData);
        adapter.setOnClickCheckBoxListener(new OnClickCheckBoxListener() {

            @Override
            public void OnClick(View v, Quote item, int pos) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                WriteLog.d(QuoteList.this.getLocalClassName(), "click");
                if (item.getIs_favourist()==0) {
                    dataHeper.AddFavourites(String.valueOf(item.getId()));
                    listData.get(pos).setIs_favourist(1);
                }else{
                    dataHeper.DeleteFavourites(String.valueOf(item.getId()));
                    listData.get(pos).setIs_favourist(0);
                }

                adapter.setData(listData);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        });
        if (listData.size()==0) {
            tv_empty.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else{
            tv_empty.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        lv.setSelection(currentPostion);
        currentPostion =0;
        if (dialogLoading.isShowing()) {
            dialogLoading.dismiss();
        }

        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: it would be nice if you could post the stacktrace of the exception you got. is QuoteList declared in your manifest ?

Comment: well what is the error

Comment: @blackbelt yes it has declared

Comment: @tyczj no error, but it's always force close, maybe it wrong codes, or something problem?

Comment: You need to tell is the error otherwise we can't help you. "How to make it work?" does not help anyone.

Comment: if it force closes there is obviously an error

Comment: just look at the logcat when you click the button and send us the red colored error messages. These are your errors. :)

Comment: @tyczj i've update a complete code of QuoteList

Comment: posting the class isnt going to help we need the error, if you dont give us the error you have you will not get an answer

Comment: @tyczj it's no error yet, i don't know why, but it's only keep force close when button clicked

Comment: @tyczj but it can be run on AVD, :(

Comment: probably he never declared `QuoteList` in androidmanifest. by the way when you test for equality between two strings you should use `.equals()` not `==` because this`==` equates to reference while `equals()` equates to value.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Use below code to read data as

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if(extras == null) {
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Data Found...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
else{
String category = extras.getString("category");
if(category.equals("ok"))
 {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "category Value :"+category, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }

}
```

One more thing to compare two strings you should use .equals() method. [== only compares references only ]

Hope this will solve your problem.