# How to pass object from an activity to another activity extending tab activity?

Tags: android, object, android-intent, android-tabactivity

I have my Starting activity which extends activity, from here I want to pass an object to a next activity that extends tab activity. How can I implement put extra in my starting and how can i implement get extra in my activity that extends tab activity?

Comment: the object you are passing between activities must implement either Parcelable or Serializable interface,then you can get the object by  using getParcelableExtra or getSerializableExtra method,check [this](http://www.developerphil.com/parcelable-vs-serializable/) post out

Comment: Take a look on this [Link1][1] as well as [Link2][2]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265913/how-to-use-putextra-and-getextra-for-string-data
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233873/how-to-get-extra-data-from-intent-in-android