# How to check value of two fields in URL?

Tags: java, android, json, string

Hello guys I have one url for my which is connected through id, 
here I am using user_login_id and response is look like this..

```
    {"interestreceived":[{"received_detail_id":2783,"interest_id":1288,"name":"Monali Patel","profile_id":"GM453843",
     "image":"","cast":"Not Willing to specify","age":"24","location":"","user_status":"Accept"}]}
```

Here I have received_detail_id in above JSON,,

now in my next JSON Response

here I am using both ids,and in my code I am using put extra and get extra to pass values

```
String matchId=this.getIntent().getStringExtra("received_detail_id");  
String Id=this.getIntent().getStringExtra("user_login_id");
```

USER URL:

```
USER_URL="http://mywebsitename.com/webservice/interestreceiveddetail?version=apps&received_detail_id="+matchId+"&user_login_id="+Id;
```

Is this right way to do?because I am not getting output

Comment: have you check matchId and Id before detail url call ? and also check url in browser see what response are came.

Comment: response is perfect there is no problem,but tell me that the way i am concatenate the URL string is right or wrong?

Comment: obviously if is not creating any problem then you in right track brother.

Comment: @HareshChhelana I mean is this right way to concatenate the strings   USER_URL="http://mywebsitename.com/webservice/interestreceiveddetail?version=apps&received_detail_id="+matchId+"&user_login_id="+Id;

Comment: @HareshChhelana it shows error like this Key user_login_id expected String but value was a java.lang.Long.  The default value <null> was returned.

Comment: I think you passing user_login_id value as Long and try to get using String so try this : String Id=String.valueOf(this.getIntent().getLongExtra("user_login_id",0));

Comment: @HareshChhelana whne i use sysout below your line it shows 0 instead 2650,can you tell me why?

Comment: can you please post how you pass those both id ?

Comment: simply using putextra and getextra

Comment: post your code how you passing it

Comment: intent.putExtra("id", id);  StringId=this.getIntent().getStringExtra("id");

Comment: I think you are passing same id in different pages,check your putextra again from where your are passing values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this it will give you way to how to use putextra and getextra  [How to use putExtra() and getExtra() for string data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265913/how-to-use-putextra-and-getextra-for-string-data)

Comment: yeah I got it I was passing wrong parameter with that Thanks it works fine now,vote and accept

Comment: Happy to help you..enjoy