# Android listview onclicklistener activity

Tags: java, android, xml, listview, onclicklistener

I want that if I click in the listview on 'Leerlingenraad' that he opens the class Leerlingenraad with leerlingenraad.xml and if I click on Contact that he opens the class Contact with contact.xml I have found a lot of topics of this but it won't work. Does anyone know what's wrong in my script? Please don't rate this down.

Myclass.java:

```
package com.example.myapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem.*;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.HashMap;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.widget.AdapterView; 
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter; 
import android.widget.ListView; 
import android.widget.TextView; 
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast; 

public class Myclass extends Activity {

// List view
private ListView lv;

// Listview Adapter
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

// Search EditText
EditText inputSearch;


// ArrayList for Listview
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> onderneming;


/**
 * Called when the activity is first created.
*/

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.myclass);


String onderneming[] = {"Leerlingenraad", "Medezeggenschapsraad", "3", "4", "5", "6", "Contact"};

lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);

// Adding items to listview
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.product_name, onderneming);
lv.setAdapter(adapter);       

/**
 * Enabling Search Filter
 * */
inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {

// When user changed the Text
Ondernemerschap.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);  

}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
int arg3) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
}
});

lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,

final int position, long id) {

String main = lv.getSelectedItem().toString();

}
});
}
private ListView getListView() {
return null;

}
}
```

myclass.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

android:id="@+id/background"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/pallasrood"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView

android:id="@+id/imageView1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="100dp"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:src="@drawable/android" />

<EditText android:id="@+id/inputSearch"

android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"android:hint="Zoek de onderneming.."
android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"/>

<ListView

android:id="@+id/list_view"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_below="@+id/inputSearch"
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent" >

</ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Androidmanifest.xml

```
<activity android:name=".Leerlingenraad"    
android:label="Pallasapp">
</activity>
```

Comment: It sounds like you need to use Activities. Create a new activity for `Leerlingenraad` and `Contact` and use `Intent`s and `startActivity()` to change to these activities.

Comment: You should look into [this](http://developer.android.com/training/index.html), that'll help you a lot. Especially the [Starting Another Activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html) chapter.

Comment: Can you paste you listview screen shot so that we understand what you are asking for

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/J5FRT.png

Comment: I don't understand the developer.android.com tutorials. I know how to start an activity but not with an listview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you already have your detail activity, which I called `OndernemingDetailActivity`

In your ListView activity:

```
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            Intent in = new Intent(this, OndernemingDetailActivity.class);
            //Send onderneming
            in.putExtra("selected_onderneming", adapter.getItem(i));
            startActivity(in);
        }
    });
```

Then in your detail view you'd get the "selected_onderneming" from the bundle like so:

```
String selectedOnderneming;
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    if(extras != null)
        onderneming = extras.getString("selected_onderneming"); // retrieve the selected onderneming
```

This is the quickest way to get the extras out of the bundle. Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5265952/1449972) post for a more robust and safe way to do so.

You can then show the data you need of the 'selected onderneming'. I hope this answers your question.

Comment: Do you have the OndernemingDetailActivity class? If so, try replacing `this` with `getActivity()`

Comment: owh I must change the activity class haha

Comment: okay I will try it and accept your answer, when it my don't work can I contact you then on stack exchange?

Comment: What must I do with the OnderneminDetailActivity class?

Comment: I suggest you read a tutorial like [this one](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html). That should explain everything about list views and how to use them.