# Parse.com ListView OnClickListener Passes Dynamic ImageView

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, parse-platform

I am facing a problem with `onItemClickListener`. I have a `ListView` which contains strings as well as two images from `parse.com` table. I want to show the strings and images (that i have pushed in `parse.com` database) in another activity after I click on any item. I successfully get all the strings using `getIntent()` but I'm not able to find the solution to fetch the images from `ListView` item dynamically.

What is the best way to acomplish this?

Comment: U decode a parse file,s url to a thumb in the list adapter. So save aref to it so u can pass to new activity. If u use a good image framework ( uil or aquery ... ) it will have been cached when u call for the urls bmp the second time

Comment: i dont understand...can u please share the code to do the same !!

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the click event can provide the file Url's string value to another activity via the [putExtra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265913/how-to-use-putextra-and-getextra-for-string-data)

look at the [docs](https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseFile.html) for calling $FileObj.'getUrl' that retrieves url as Type string

working with images in persistence you should store both full-sz and thumb-sz, working with the thumb in list-adapter context.

So, if u have store the bitmap for the thumbs file on parse, with **"getUrl"** you can operate on the URL value of the file( its useful in frameworks like 'Volley')

Read up on [using adapters](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView) particularly "getView" to load the bitmap whenever you need to provide the bmp to a list adapter from your image lib.

Pass the File-Url-string to new activity in "Extra String Value"

Use [Volley](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/) for your networking/file retreival and bitmap caching. bit of a guess but Volley and parse should be OK.