# What's the easiest way to access listview item string?

Tags: java, android, listview

I've got a listview and I want to start a new activity when clicking on an item in that listview. How do I access the variables of that item from the new activity?

Edit: My listview is populated via an Asynctask and an RSS Feed. I want to access one of the items in the array and read out its url.

Comment: if you start the activity you can transfer that variable to the new activity

Comment: Before you start the second Activity, you can [attach additional data to the `Intent`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265913/how-to-use-putextra-and-getextra-for-string-data).

Comment: I don't know how, the listview is fed with an Asynctask (RSS Feed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method 1**:

you can store it in an object of a custom class (which implements Serilizable) on click of listview and pass that object via intent. Make sure :

```
  //to pass :
  intent.putExtra("MyClass", obj);  

 // to retrieve object in second Activity
getIntent().getSerializableExtra("MyClass");
```

**Method 2**(not recommended):

Create a static custom class and store the variables in onclick to that class instance.

for Static Class A {...}

```
//To pass
A.variable = "stored value";

//retrieve
 String s = A.variable;
```

**Method 3**

Use SharePreferences. Recommended only if you need to remember what user clicked last time he was using the app.

Comment: I worded my question wrongly, I know how to do that and transfered the list item position. But I have to access the array which fills the listview.

Comment: you can even store/retrieve arrays in the same above way.

Comment: I figured out a different way to do it. I made the array public in the class with the AsyncTask and Intent, then I was able to transfer the variable. Thank you anyway!