# Android putExtra cannot resolve symbol

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to transfer a string from one activity to another in android. I'm working off of this answer: [How to use putExtra() and getExtra() for string data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265913/how-to-use-putextra-and-getextra-for-string-data)

However, I think I'm doing something really basic incorrectly. When I type "`i.putExtra`" I get the error "cannot resolve putExtra." Do I need to import something to use `putExtra`?

In the documentation for `putExtra` it seems that I should be able to use it as long as I've imported `android.content`.Intent, which I have.

Comment: You surely are missing something basic. Could you post your code or a print screen? It is probably a matter of mistyping something

Comment: Can you please post the relevant code sniplet which you have there?

Comment: You're right. I didn't put the code in the onCreate method, just in the activity. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the code into the `OnCreate()` statement.