# intent.putExtra() in pending intent not working

Tags: android, android-intent

I am passing a pending intent through alarmreceiver, from a service class. But, after the pendingIntent fires, the intent.putExtra() information is not being received by the broadcastreceiver class. Here is my code for firing the pendingIntent

```
Intent aint = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), id, aint, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
aint.putExtra("msg", msg);
aint.putExtra("phone", phone);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

The alarm receiver class is below

```
public String msg, phonen;

@Override
public void  onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    msg = extras.getString("msg");
    phonen = extras.getString("phone");

    Log.d("onReceive", "About to execute MyTask");
    Toast.makeText(context,msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

The **msg** information in toast, that is being received from pending intent, is not being shown. Instead, a blank toast is shown.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Try this

```
Intent aint = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
aint.putExtra("msg", msg);
aint.putExtra("phone", phone);



PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
    getApplicationContext(),
    id, 
    aint,
    // as stated in the comments, this flag is important!
    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Comment: For those looking at this and have the .putExtra methods before attaching to PendingIntent, the `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` is important, so try that before moving on to another solution.

Comment: I had a totally different issue but this solves it. According to [`PendingIntent`'s documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent): "A common mistake people make is to create multiple PendingIntent objects with Intents that only vary in their "extra" contents, expecting to get a different PendingIntent each time. **This does not happen**. The parts of the Intent that are used for matching are the same ones defined by [Intent.filterEquals](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#filterEquals(android.content.Intent)). "

Comment: Part 2: "If you use two Intent objects that are equivalent as per `Intent.filterEquals`, then you will get the same `PendingIntent` for both of them." And looking at [`Intent.filterEquals`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#filterEquals(android.content.Intent)) it filters on "action, data, type, class, and categories [...] his does not compare *any extra data* included in the intents"

Answer (score 12):

Remember to put an unique id in the PendingIntent constructor, or you could get some weird thing when you try to get the putExtra values.

```
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
           getApplicationContext(), 
           UUID.randomUUID().hashCode(), 
           aint, 
           PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
    );
```

Comment: Why putting random id?

Comment: Bad idea to use a random id

Comment: In some cases you need a unique ID, as Google suggests. It solved the issue for me in my case. Here for reference:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent#:~:text=There%20are%20two%20typical%20ways%20to%20deal%20with%20this

Comment: This fixed my issue. I had two pending intents from a notification that both had their id set to zero. Some of the extras from one intent were getting added to the other.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `getStringExtra()` and be sure the String are not null:

```
     Intent intent = getIntent();    
     msg = intent.getStringExtra("msg");
     phonen = intent.getStringExtra("phone");

     if(msg!=null){
      Toast.makeText(context,msg,
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }
```

and reverse Your putExtras before PendingIntent:

```
   Intent aint = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
   aint.putExtra("msg", msg);
   aint.putExtra("phone", phone);
   PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), id, aint, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are first initialize Intent and add to PendingIntent. After that you are adding info in intent. You should add info to intent then add this intent to PendingIntent.

Answer (score 1):

In my case i was missing `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` as flag.

Answer (score 0):

```js
 final Intent my_intent = new Intent(this.context , Alarm_Receiver.class);

    //put in extra string into my intent
    //tell the clock that the user pressed the "alarm on button"
    my_intent.putExtra("extra" , 1);
    int state = my_intent.getExtras().getInt("extra");
    Log.i("extraa" , "the state in the main activity in alarm on Button is: " + state);
```

I had the same problem and I found out that you should put the `putExtra` before you involve the Intent

Answer (score 0):

Please Use `FLAG_IMMUTABLE | PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`

Comment: Why? Please read [answer],

Answer (score 0):

In kotlin, I solved that problem like that when trying to to start a service from another service class:

```kotlin
var float_intent = Intent(this,FloatingViewService::class.java)
float_intent.putExtra("sended_name",customer_name)
val pending_float_intent = PendingIntent.getService(
    this, UUID.randomUUID().hashCode(), float_intent, FLAG_IMMUTABLE or PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use

`PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`

Only use

PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE

Full code snippet below

```
 val pendingIntent: PendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
    /* context = */ context,
    /* requestCode = */
    0,
    /* intent = */
    intentData,
    /* flags = */
    PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
)
```