# How do I pass a value (putExtra) through a notification? (Android Studio Kotlin)

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I have a code that creates a notification:

```
val notId = 100;
        val channelId = "test"
        val channelName = "test"
        val notificationIntent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java).putExtra("music", "off")
        val contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            this,
            0, notificationIntent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT
        )
        val notificationChannel: NotificationChannel = NotificationChannel(channelId, channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT)
        notificationChannel.description = "test"
        val notificationManager = getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel)
        val builder = Notification.Builder(this, channelId)
        builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
            .setContentTitle("notification")
            .setContentText("test")
            .setAutoCancel(true)
        notificationManager.notify(notId, builder.build())
```

The problem with this code is that it cannot pass putExtra and this code launches MainActivity, which I certainly don’t need. How can I solve this problem? Please help me =>

The code below checks the value and unfortunately it return "null":

```
 override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
    thread { while (true){
        println(intent?.getStringExtra("music"))
        sleep(2000)
    }
    }
    return Service.START_STICKY
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [intent.putExtra() in pending intent not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29846244/intent-putextra-in-pending-intent-not-working)

Comment: @cutiko I am new to Kotlin so I don’t know how to work with broadcast yet. and so thanks a lot