# Cannot assign variable value to a string from extra.getString();

Tags: android, string, android-intent

New to android, I'm currently trying to send a `String` value from one `Activity` to another. I have looked through several threads like [How to use putExtra() and getExtra() for string data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265913/how-to-use-putextra-and-getextra-for-string-data) for an answer, but I cannot get it to work.

The string I want to send is:

```
public void golf(View view)  {
    Intent intent = new Intent(SearchSport.this, EventList.class);
    intent.putExtra("type", "golf");
    startActivity(intent);
```

and my receiver looks like

```
String type;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_event_list);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    if ( extras != null)
        type = extras.getString("type");

    if (type == "golf"){
        TextView eventName      = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.EOName);
        TextView eventTime      = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.EOTime);
        TextView eventLocation  = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.EOLocation);

        DatabaseOperations dop = new DatabaseOperations(ctx);
        Cursor CR = dop.getInformation(1);
        CR.moveToFirst();

        eventName.setText(CR.getString(1));
        eventTime.setText(CR.getString(7) + " " + CR.getString(8) + ". " + CR.getString(9) + " kl. " + CR.getString(10) + ":" + CR.getString(11));
        eventLocation.setText(CR.getString(4));}

    else {Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Error in Type.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();}
```

I have no Idea what's wrong here. The app displays the `toast` everytime I test it, instead of filling out the `TextViews` with the data from my database entry.

EDIT: Code has been changed based on answers, but the problem has not yet been solved. Writing `if (type.equals("golf")){}` instead of `if (type == "golf"){}` crashed the app.

EDIT 2: Problem solved! Fixed case sensitivity, used `.equals` instead of `==`, and wrote the receiver as

```
if(getIntent().hasExtra("Type"))
    type = getIntent().getStringExtra("Type");
```

In the end, it turns out is was the virtual device I used which crashed the app, for as of yet unknown reasons. When tested on an actual android phone, the app works as intented.

Thanks to everyone for their help!

Comment: key is wrong use 'Type' instead 'type' like : extras.getString("Type").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
if(getIntent().hasExtra("Type"))
        type = getIntent().getStringExtra("Type");
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the key it is case sensitive :

```
  type = extras.getString("Type");
```

Comment: here you can do something like this

Comment: ignore addeaccidently

Comment: Fixing that did not fix the problem

Comment: @RuneUggerhøj did u solved the issues with using `equals` also ?

Answer (score 1):

Key is wrong when try to get `String` from `Intent` `Extra` :

```
type = extras.getString("type");
```

Replace with :

```
type = extras.getString("Type");
```

Note : Also use `equals()` instead `==` for comparing `String`

```
 if (type.equals("golf")){
```

Comment: maybe you could suggest the op something for this `type == "golf"`

Comment: writing if `(type.equals("golf")){` instead of `if (type == "golf"){` crashes the program

Answer (score 1):

1) First keys are case sensitive

2) pass as

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle() 
bundle.putString("type","golf");

intent.putExtras(bundle);
```

after that get it using

```
Bundle received = i.getExtras();
received.getString("type");
```

Answer (score 0):

As  you are passing the value using Extra. You must have to catch that using `getStringExtra();` and the Key must be case sensitive.

```
Intent i = getIntent();
type = i.getStringExtra("Type");
```