# Passing parameters in Intentw using URI from "App A" to "App B"-Android

Tags: java, android, uri

I cant solve my problem soo I need help :)

I have two Apps "App A" and "App B". In "App A" im entry two numerbs(in two diffrent edittext) after that i click button "sendwithdata"(here Im passing parameters from edittext using URI). My "App 2" catch parameters from "App A", adds two numbers and displays the result. 
I thik its something wrong with geting parameters from uri.

**App A**

```
public class WprowadzanieLiczbActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_wprowadzanie_liczb);

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_wprowadzanie_liczb, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void sendwithData(View view) {
    String adres2 = adresUriSumy();
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(adres2);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
    startActivity(intent);
}

private String adresUriSumy() {
    EditText liczbaAInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.A);
    Editable liczbaA = liczbaAInput.getText();
    String liczbaAParam = String.format("liczbaA=%s", liczbaA);

    EditText liczbaBInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.B);
    Editable liczbaB = liczbaBInput.getText();
    String liczbaBParam = String.format("liczbaA=%s", liczbaB);

    String podstawowyAdres = "calculator://wwsis.com.pl/suma";

    String adres2 = String.format("%s?%s%s", podstawowyAdres, liczbaAParam, liczbaBParam);

    return (adres2);
}}
```

**App B**

```
public class WyswietlanieActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_wyswietlanie);
    wezDanezUri();

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_wyswietlanie, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


private void wezDanezUri() {
    Uri uri = getIntent().getData();
    if (uri != null) {
        double liczbaA = getDoubleParam(uri, "liczbaA");
        double liczbaB = getDoubleParam(uri, "liczbaB");

        double suma = liczbaA + liczbaB;

        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.wyswietlacz);


        textView.setText(liczbaA + liczbaB + Double.toString(suma));

    }


}

private double getDoubleParam(Uri uri, String queryParamName) {
    String wzorzmiennej = uri.getQueryParameter(queryParamName);
    double value = 0.0;
    try {
        value = Double.parseDouble(wzorzmiennej);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    } // NumberFormatException or NullPointerException
    return (value);
}}
```

**App B manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".WyswietlanieActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <data android:scheme="calculator" android:host="wwsis.com.pl" android:path="/suma"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: I just got this working, I'll post an answer.

Comment: Im counting on you :)

Comment: Let me know if it works for you!

Comment: @DanielNugent yeees its working :) Thank you soo much. I made stupid mistakes. Only think what i dont understand is why i cant use Editable, but i will figureout.

Comment: Nice, glad it's working!  I actually didn't even test with `Editable`, I just assumed it would not work.  Actually, now that I think about it, it might just automatically call `toString()` on the Editables when you use them in `String.format()`, so for that it might work as you had them before.

Comment: @DanielNugent its work also with "my" Editable.. Once again thx for help. Best regards

Comment: Nice, I'll update the answer just so that it doesn't have incorrect info!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran the code and figured out where the problems were.

The main problem was that you were missing `&` between the parameters, so that made the first parameter contain everything after `liczbaA`, and the second parameter was blank.

You also accidentally used `liczbaA` twice in the `adresUriSumy()` method.

I switched it to explicitly use Strings for the `EditText` values, but it would work as you have it as well, since it will implicitly call `toString()` on each `Editable` when you use it in `String.format()`.

The last issue was formatting the result in App B.

First, here are the fixes from App A that made it work:

```
private String adresUriSumy() {
    //Use Strings from the EditText fields:
    EditText liczbaAInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.A);
    String liczbaA = liczbaAInput.getText().toString();
    String liczbaAParam = String.format("liczbaA=%s", liczbaA);

    //Use liczbaB below:
    EditText liczbaBInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.B);
    String liczbaB = liczbaBInput.getText().toString();
    String liczbaBParam = String.format("liczbaB=%s", liczbaB);//modified

    String podstawowyAdres = "calculator://wwsis.com.pl/suma";

    //notice the & below
    String adres2 = String.format("%s?%s&%s", podstawowyAdres, liczbaAParam, liczbaBParam);

    return (adres2);
}
```

Here is the fix made in App B:

```
private void wezDanezUri() {
    Uri uri = getIntent().getData();

    if (uri != null) {

        double liczbaA = getDoubleParam(uri, "liczbaA");
        double liczbaB = getDoubleParam(uri, "liczbaB");

        double suma = liczbaA + liczbaB;

        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.wyswietlacz);

        //modified:
        textView.setText(Double.toString(liczbaA) + " + " + Double.toString(liczbaB) + " = " + Double.toString(suma));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be using putExtra() on the Intent class.

See [the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) for an example.  Here's [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265913/how-to-use-putextra-and-getextra-for-string-data) that shows how to do this.