# setText from a class for another

Tags: android

I am really new to android. And my English speaking is not good. So,I was going to get a username using an `EditText` and set it to a `TextView` But the problem is that the EditText is in the first class (`MyActivity`),and the `TextView` is in the second class(`MyAcyivity2`).
I did everything such as `FindViewById` and....
but when I set on a click listener :

```
Textview1.setText(EditText1.getText())
```

and open the app, by clicking on button it says: Unfortunately app has stopped.

what to do?

Comment: you need to send value of EditText to MyActivity2 by put extra, like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265913/how-to-use-putextra-and-getextra-for-string-data

Comment: Pay attention to your app debug or logcat, it provides you usefull information such what caused the problem you are facing. See the answer for how to fix it.

Answer (score 5):

**In MyActivity :**

```
EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
```

***On button click, inside `onClickListener` :***

```
void onClick(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MyActivity.this, MyActivity2.class);
    intent.putExtra("myString", et.getText().toString());
    startActivity(intent);

}
```

**In MyActivity2 inside `onCreate()`**

```
String myString = getIntent().getStringExtra("myString");
TextView tv = findViewById(R.id.textView1); 
tv.setText(myString);
```

Comment: Thank you a lot . I read your answer but I forgot to say Thank you . :-) .