# Pass the value from activity 1 to activity 2 to do calculation and show the result

Tags: java, android, android-intent

this is my first activity, i want to pass the value to second activity to do calculation and show the result in the textview.But I dont know why when i key in all the detail at activity 1, and click the custom button it jump out from the app

```
 public void onClick(View v){
        switch (v.getId())
        {
    case R.id.customMarco:

                if(gender.getText().toString().equals("") || age.getText().toString().equals("")||
                    height.getText().toString().equals("")||weight.getText().toString().equals("")||
                    activity.getText().toString().equals("")||goal.getText().toString().equals(""))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please key in all your detail above !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else {
                    String cal = finalCal_result.getText().toString();
                    String carb = carb_result.getText().toString();
                    String protein = protein_result.getText().toString();
                    String fat = fat_result.getText().toString();

                    Intent intent = new Intent(this, CustomMarco.class);
                    intent.putExtra("Cal", cal);
                    intent.putExtra("Carb", carb);
                    intent.putExtra("Protein", protein);
                        intent.putExtra("Fat", fat);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                    break;
}
```

This is my second activity, to get the valur from activity 1 and do calculation and show the result in textview cp. But I dont know why when i key in all the detail at activity 1, and click the custom button it jump out from the app

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_custom__marco);

          cal = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.field_cal);
          String calNum =getIntent().getStringExtra("Cal");
          cal.setText ( calNum );
          cal.setOnClickListener(this);

          carb = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.field_carb);
          String carbNum =getIntent().getStringExtra("Carb");
          carb.setText ( carbNum );
          carb.setOnClickListener(this);

          Button setButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.setButton);
          setButton.setOnClickListener(this);

          TextView cp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cp);

          float cal_n = Float.parseFloat(calNum);
          float carb_n = Float.parseFloat(carbNum);

          int carbPValue = calculateCP(cal_n,carb_n);
          cp.setText(String.valueOf(carbPValue) + " %");
        }

        private int calculateCP(float cal_n, float carb_n){
            return (int) ((carb_n/cal_n)*4*100);
        }
```

here the log cat error

```
12-03 21:25:39.284 
28640-28640/com.example.sam.iifym E/AndroidRuntime: 
FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.sam.iifym/com.example.sam.iifym.CustomMarco}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "3809 cal"
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2383)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2435)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:168)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1379)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5434)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:852)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:619)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "3809 cal"
at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:375)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:366)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:332)
at com.example.sam.iifym.CustomMarco.onCreate(CustomMarco.java:59)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5224)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1151)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2347)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2435) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:168) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1379) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5434) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:852) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:619) 
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What do you mean by  `"it jump put from the app"`? *CustomMarco* activity is not shown?

Comment: Which error you got? Post logcat here.

Comment: sorry is it jump out from the app

Comment: @WgSam No log errors?

Comment: @Rami posted the log cat error
hlp check

Comment: @WgSam did you get your solution?

Comment: @Chirag Savsani ya solve it , thank. But i face another problem, would you please hlp me take a look. here the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34085608/passing-number-from-1st-activity-to-the-number-picker?noredirect=1#comment55925191_34085608

Comment: @WgSam If your got help from my answer then you can accept my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
String carb = extras.getString("Carb");
```

for more info just check this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5265952/2074990

Comment: regarding the logcat-outout you have an invalid integer. Makes my answer obsolete... though it is the nicer approach :)

Comment: i face another problem, would you please hlp me take a look. here the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34085608/passing-number-from-1st-activity-to-the-number-picker?noredirect=1#comment55925191_34085608

Answer (score 0):

> Caused by: java.lang.**NumberFormatException**: Invalid int: "3809 cal"

You're trying to convert the `String` `"3809 cal"` to `int/float`, while `"3809 cal"` is not a valid format of `int/float`.

Check your `cal` String in the first activity, it must be `"3809"` instead of `"3809 cal"`.

Comment: but i really dunno where the 3809 cal from i already check there is the code from activity 1 before i pass to the 2nd activity i got create this calculation int finalCalResultValue = calculateFinalCal(tdeeResultValue); finalCal_result.setText(finalCalResultValue + " cal");

Comment: With  `finalCal_result.setText(finalCalResultValue + " cal");` , you append `"cal"` to your integer so it became an invalid format of integer.

Comment: Thank @Rami , solve the problem,but now i face another problem, would you please hlp me take a look. here the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34085608/passing-number-from-1st-activity-to-the-number-picker?noredirect=1#comment55925191_34085608

Answer (score 0):

There is problem in your string.

LogCat says ***`Invalid int: "3809 cal"`***

You pass Invalid data in that string.

You can just pass only **Integer** for convert **String** to **Float**

Example : 
 Valid String is **"3809"**.

Instead of **"3809 cal"**.

Comment: but i really dunno where the 3809 cal from
i already check there is the code from activity 1 before i pass to the 2nd activity i got create this calculation 

 int finalCalResultValue = calculateFinalCal(tdeeResultValue);
 finalCal_result.setText(finalCalResultValue + " cal");