# Android Intent (Send Data From Third Activity To First Activity)

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-studio

I have made 3 kinds of activity.

The order of activity is A, B, C.

Firstly I would like to show a type of 'TextView' at Activity B by inputting from C in terms of a type of 'EditText', and then to let show the content(of B) into Activity A in terms of 'TextView' finally.

Could you show or inform how to solve this sequence action?

Also could you share some example codes(source), if possible?

Thanks for your cooperation and concern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like this. First get String from EditText in activity by this method.

EditText.getText().ToString() and save it to String.

then Start an Intent to change the activity and then put that string in that 
Intent like this.

Intent.putExtra(your String, it's name).
Then use intent.getExtra(it's name).

Check this Link.
[How to use putExtra() and getExtra() for string data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265913/how-to-use-putextra-and-getextra-for-string-data)

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! I want to ask one more... Could you explain about "intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT"??? In my opinion, I can use this in my application, too