# Use same SQLite database for multiple activities

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-activity, android-lifecycle

I am pretty new to Android and trying to build a food ordering application, I am having problems on the checkout page where a database should receive data from 6 different activities, however it only receives from the first activity launched and all the other fail. Can somebody give me a clue on how to manage that? Thanks in advance to all

```
public class BaconBurgerActivity extends Activity
{

    ImageView bacon_burger;
    TextView bacon_burger_txt;
    TextView bacon_burger_price;
    TextView bacon_burger_qty;
    Spinner bacon_burger_spinner;
    Button bb_add_btn;
    Button bb_menu_btn;
    TextView bacon_burger_combo;
    TextView bacon_burger_juices;
    TextView bacon_burger_sides;
    TextView bacon_burger_combo_qty;
    Button bacon_burger_combo_add;
    Spinner bacon_burger_juice_spinner;
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> bacon_burger_juice_adapter;
    Spinner bacon_burger_side_spinner;
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> bacon_burger_side_adapter;
    Spinner bacon_burger_combo_qty_spinner;
    Context ctx = this;
    SQLiteDatabase db;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.bacon_burger_layout);
   //Bacon Burger Image and Text View
    bacon_burger=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.bb_main);
    bacon_burger_txt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.bb_text);
    bacon_burger_price=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.bb_price);
    bacon_burger_qty=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.bb_qty);
    //Bacon Burger Spinner
    Integer[] options = new Integer[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    bacon_burger_spinner=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.bb_spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<Integer> bacon_burger_adapter =new ArrayAdapter<>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,options);
    bacon_burger_adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    bacon_burger_spinner.setAdapter(bacon_burger_adapter);

    //Bacon Burger Buttons
    bb_add_btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bb_add);
    bb_menu_btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bb_back);

    //Combo Image and Text View
    bacon_burger_combo=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.bb_combo);
    bacon_burger_juices=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.juices);
    bacon_burger_sides=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.sides);
    bacon_burger_combo_qty=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.bb_combo_qty);
    //Combo Button
    bacon_burger_combo_add=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bb_combo_add);
    //Combo Juice Spinner
    bacon_burger_juice_spinner=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.bb_juice_spinner);
    bacon_burger_juice_adapter=ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.juices,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    bacon_burger_juice_adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    bacon_burger_juice_spinner.setAdapter(bacon_burger_juice_adapter);
    //Combo Side Spinner
    bacon_burger_side_spinner=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.bb_side_spinner);
    bacon_burger_side_adapter=ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.sides,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    bacon_burger_side_adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    bacon_burger_side_spinner.setAdapter(bacon_burger_side_adapter);
    //Combo Qty Spinner
    Integer[] numbers = new Integer[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    bacon_burger_combo_qty_spinner=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.bb_combo_spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<Integer> bacon_burger_combo_adapter =new ArrayAdapter<>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,numbers);
    bacon_burger_combo_adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    bacon_burger_combo_qty_spinner.setAdapter(bacon_burger_combo_adapter);


}

//Bacon Burger onClick method
public void add_btn (View view)
{
    int quantity = Integer.parseInt(bacon_burger_spinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
    float price =(float) 6.52;
    float total= ((quantity)*(price));
    String bb_order=bacon_burger_spinner.getSelectedItem().toString()+" Bacon Burger";
    DatabaseOperations DB = new DatabaseOperations(ctx);
    DB.putInformation(DB,bb_order,null,total);
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"ITEM ADDED TO BASKET", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

public void menu_btn (View view)
{
    Intent bb_intent=new Intent(BaconBurgerActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(bb_intent);
}

//Bacon Burger Combo onClick method

public void add_combo_btn (View view)
{
    int combo_quantity= Integer.parseInt(bacon_burger_combo_qty_spinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
    float bb_combo_price=(float)8.55;
    float bb_combo_total= ((combo_quantity)*(bb_combo_price));
    String bb_combo_order=bacon_burger_combo_qty_spinner.getSelectedItem().toString()+" Bacon Burger Combo";
    String bb_juice_side=bacon_burger_side_spinner.getSelectedItem().toString()+bacon_burger_juice_spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
    DatabaseOperations DB = new DatabaseOperations(ctx);
    DB.putInformation(DB,bb_combo_order,bb_juice_side,bb_combo_total);
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"ITEM ADDED TO BASKET", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    }

}
```

Comment: How do your activities give data to the checkout page?

Comment: check your connection in other activities there are two reason of  aborting of query first connection problem and second incorrect SQL statement.create log and sort out problem according log error.

Comment: You should be holding the data generated by these activities probably in a static environment (some sort of buffer), so when you reach the checkout activity you can just query this static context. Basically you grab the info from memory.

Comment: Shamas S  - I uploaded the code of one of the activities that send data to the database I have used the same statement with different names for all other 5 activities

Comment: Hi MarkSkayff, can you explain me a bit more on that? I have no idea on how to do that, I have no programming backgorund so somethings are really difficult for me to understand

Comment: Please post the code of your `DatabaseOperations`

Answer (score 0):

Explaining what @MarkSkayff said: passing data between the activities.

When you're calling the second activity, you can add Extras to your Intent. For example:

```
Intent bb_intent=new Intent(BaconBurgerActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
bb_intent.putExtra("total",total);
startActivity(bb_intent);
```

and on your MainActivity's onCreate Method, you can load this Extra using

```
getIntent().getFloatExtra("total",0f); //0f is the default value, in case the float isn't found.
```

You can read more about Intent Extras here:
[How to use putExtra() and getExtra() for string data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265913/how-to-use-putextra-and-getextra-for-string-data)

And on the CheckOut Activity, send the data to the Database.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, I actually solved it by closing the database after every data insertion and now it is working fine. Thanks