# How to use getter and setter method in 2 differen java fila

Tags: java, android, object

I have a problem about object oriented programming. I have a DatePicker and i set the values in the DateSettings.java, and im trying to get data in main activity. And im using eventButton just for testing if i got the data or not. Here gitHub file:
https://github.com/azatgoktas/nekadarkaldi

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-date-picker-example/

Comment: @mjstam i dont have problem with datapicker. I have problem how can i get data in mainactivity which i set in datesettings.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to pass your event object to MainActivity. One way could be, create a class like below

```
public class Example {
    // sharedInstance
    private static Example sharedInstance = new Example();

    // to store/ pass events
    ArrayList<Events> eventsArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    // private constructor
    private Example() {
    }

    // get sharedInstance
    public static Example getSharedInstance() {
        return sharedInstance;
    }

    public void addToEvents(Events events) {
        eventsArrayList.add(events);
    }
}
```

in your DateSettings after you create event object, `Example.getSharedInstance().addToEvents(event);`

and then in your MainActivity you can get this event object

```
 eventButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        //JUST FOR TESTİNG
            event = Example.getSharedInstance().eventsArrayList.get(0);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),event.getDay() + ". day", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: This is exactly what i want. But i have one more question. it always turn the value which i selected first. Im adding 3 different date. but it turn which i added first.

Comment: keep on adding events to eventsArrayList and then you can iterate through the list. for (Events event : eventsArrayList) {// do something with it}

Answer (score 1):

You don't need different java files here. I think you wan't to get the date from a datepicker object.
At first create a DatepickeDialog then set the listener. You will get the date in onDateSet() method.

```
private void showStartDatePicker() {
Calendar startDateCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), startDatePickerListener, startDateCalendar
        .get(Calendar.YEAR), startDateCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
        startDateCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
DatePicker datePicker = datePickerDialog.getDatePicker();
datePickerDialog.show();}
```

Listener for datepicker:

```
private final DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener startDatePickerListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                      int dayOfMonth) {
    startDateCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
    startDateCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
    startDateCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
    // your code here
}};
```

Answer (score 0):

Mate, there are many ways for transferring data between different Activities. You should've read about it your self, but two most common ways are via [Intents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265913/how-to-use-putextra-and-getextra-for-string-data)
and [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/intl/in/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html).

Research a little bit more before you ask more questions, please.

Comment: So i apologize for my question. Basicly im asking how can i get data from two different java files with using Objects.

Comment: Basically, if you had opened the links I provided, you'd have known