# How to pass value from Activity to a Service in Android?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service

I need access a simple int variable which holds an editText element value. The value is stored as a public field on my Activity class. On my Service, I created an object from my activity class:

```
CheckActivity check = new CheckActivity();
```

and I am trying to access it by:

```
check.getFirstPosition();
```

but it returns zero. What should I do to pass the value from an Activity to a Service?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lnd0oPSzoJg that is a BIG question. A service can be bound or started, in the same process in which case you can simply use a public static variable on either side (service or activity) in a separate service you can use messengers or AIDL  by the way activities are started as intents not CheckActivity check = new CheckActivity();

Comment: Making the variable static worked, thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot create an object like that from your service. I think you are new to Java. When you do `CheckActivity check = new CheckActivity()` a new instance of your `CheckActivity` is created and no doubt it will return zero. Also you should never try creating objects of activities like this in android.

As far as your question is concerned you can pass your editText value to your service via a broadcast receiver.

Have a look at [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_broadcast_receivers.htm).

Also if you have the editText value before creating the service you can simply pass it as [intent extra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265913/how-to-use-putextra-and-getextra-for-string-data) , else you can use the broadcast approach.

In your service

```
broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                String action = intent.getAction();
                if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("getting_data")) {
                    intent.getStringExtra("value")
                }
            }
        };

        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        // set the custom action
        intentFilter.addAction("getting_data"); //Action is just a string used to identify the receiver as there can be many in your app so it helps deciding which receiver should receive the intent. 
        // register the receiver
        registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, intentFilter);
```

In your activity

```
Intent broadcast1 = new Intent("getting_data");
        broadcast.putExtra("value", editext.getText()+"");
        sendBroadcast(broadcast1);
```

Also declare your receiver in onCreate of activity and unregeister it in onDestroy

```
unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
```

Comment: Just curious, how can I use Broadcast Receiver on Service class to directly access editText value from some Activity class?

Comment: Declare your broadcastReceiver inside your service as shown in the tutorial. Then from your activity pass an intent with action set to that of your broadcast receiver. In your service the intent will be received inside your receiver and you can extract the value from there. Its very basic stuff. Please upvote/ accept the answer if you find it useful.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Making my variable static worked for me but I really liked your approach.

Comment: But how did you do that, by creating the activity object? Thnx for accepting btw !!!

Comment: Just added 'static' to the variable on my Activity and I was able to access it on my Service by ActivityName.variableName

Comment: @KaanDemirel BTW it's bad approach.

Comment: @ShadabAnsari I also think that but there are answers on stackOverflow which say this shouldn't be a problem, strange, not sure whether one should use static variables like this in activities. Can you say why is it bad? I just know it is bad :D

Comment: @varunkr The only reason for which I am reluctant to use static as much as possible is because those values persist and remain available throughout the app until the app is killed and that  value sometimes may or may not be what you expect at later stage.

Comment: Ok thnx, thats a valid reason !!

Answer (score 7):

You need to use intent for passing data between different Android components be it `Activity` or `Service`.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourService.class);
intent.putExtra("your_key_here", <your_value_here>);
```

And then start your service like this -

```
startService(intent);
```

Now you can use `onBind()` or `onStartCommand()` (depends on how you are using your service) to use the `intent` passed as an argument

```
String editTextValue = intent.getStringExtra("your_key_here");
```

You can use `editTextValue` anywhere you want now.

Comment: You can get the Intent object through the Service's lifecycle methods, but unlike Activity, Service does not have a getIntent() method.

Answer (score 0):

> CheckActivity check = new CheckActivity();

Never do this. Use `Intent` to create an activity instead.

> What should I do to pass the value from an Activity to a Service?

You can pass it via `Intent` using `context.startService()` method. Or, you can bind to it and pass a value via reference.

You can also consider using a `BroadcastReceiver` or `Handler`.