# Get value from another class

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to get value from another class, but when I get it in second class it is null. I think it is caused bcs when is something added to this String that code does not run.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
```

a lot of not important code.......................................

```
FirebaseDatabase database5 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference myRef5 = database5.getReference("userdata");

    myRef5.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            // This method is called once with the initial value and again
            // whenever data at this location is updated.
```

lot of not improtant code.............................................

```
mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {
```

a lot of not important code...........................................

```
new CountDownTimer(2000, 1000) {

           public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

           }
           public void onFinish() {

               progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
               textViewPleaseWait.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

               recipientEmail = marker.getTitle();
               Log.i("omg", recipientEmail);

               dialogBuilder.setMessage("Username: " + usernameAlert + "\n" + "Gender: " + genderAlert
                                       + "\n" + "Age: " + ageAlert + "\n" + marker.getSnippet() + "\n" + marker.getTitle());

               dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Send message", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                       Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SendMessage.class);
                       startActivity(intent);

                       recipientEmail = marker.getTitle();
                   }
               });

               dialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Close", null);
               dialogBuilder.show();


           }
       }.start();
```

}

And here it is.... I set value to recipientEmail when timer is done but I must run timer by clicking on marker on map. I can't set value recipientEmail outside of this timer bcs value wouldn't be same. So when I call it in another class, normally:

```
MapsActivity mapsActivity = new MapsActivity();

    recipientUsername2 = mapsActivity.getRecipientEmail();
    Log.i("values2", mapsActivity.recipientEmail);
```

And after running second activity app crashes.

```
08-28 21:34:25.943 4609-4609/com.samo.facedatefb E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.samo.facedatefb, PID: 4609
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.samo.facedatefb/com.samo.facedatefb.SendMessage}: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2464)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2526)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:169)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1421)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5549)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:964)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:759)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
    at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
    at android.util.Log.i(Log.java:160)
    at com.samo.facedatefb.SendMessage.onCreate(SendMessage.java:79)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5975)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1111)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2417)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2526) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:169) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1421) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5549) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:964) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:759)
```

Could you help me please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you create a **new**, (presumably **empty**) `MapsActivity` instance:

```
MapsActivity mapsActivity = new MapsActivity();
```

And two lines below, you try to read from it:

```
recipientUsername2 = mapsActivity.getRecipientEmail();
```

No wonder it is empty. *This MapsActivity is not the MapsActivity you're looking for...* (Just this time it is not a Jedi trick.)

Try to grasp it this way: When you set the `recipientEmail` field in MapsActivity, you write it on a piece of paper. With the `new MapsActivity()` constructor call, you get a new piece of paper from your drawer - a *different* one, and now you try to read something off that paper, which you wrote on the other one...

To be able to have that information, you have to put it somewhere - set it to an instance of a class that you pass around, set it to a field in the class you plan to use next, etc...

This time however, I think setting the `recipientEmail` String as an Extra to the `SendMail` activity would be the way to go:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SendMessage.class);
intent.putExtra("RECIPIENT_EMAIL", marker.getTitle());
startActivity(intent); //this has to be after the putExtra call
```

And when you try to access it in the `SendMail` activity:

```
String recipientEmail = null;
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if(extras == null) {
    throw new IllegalStateException("No email address found at SendMail activity!");
} else {
    recipientEmail = extras.getString("RECIPIENT_EMAIL");
}
```

Also, read the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265913/how-to-use-putextra-and-getextra-for-string-data) I usually turn to when having to deal with Extras.

Another thing: the recommended way to access object members is to set them private vland add *getter* methods and where applicable, *setter* methods. Just leaving the variables accessible is problematic.

Comment: Thanks you man for code and of course for explaining where the issue was, really appreciate it.