# How to make click event on image and show that image in another activity in android?

Tags: android

I have an array of string which contain image URL's and Text which i am showing in image view with text. here i want when user click imageview i want to get that image and will show in android activity.How can I do that

code:-

```
ImageView m_DealImage;String[] dealText = {"Install Medlife", "Install Voonik", "Install IndigoRummy","Install Chai point"};

String[] arr = new String[]{
        "http://media.vcommission.com/brand/files/vcm/3012/Medlife_CPS_MLVC2_336X280.jpg",
        "http://media.vcommission.com/brand/files/vcm/3156/Voonik_CPS_Half_Price_Fashion_Sale_728x90.jpg",
        "http://media.vcommission.com/brand/files/vcm/3144/IndigoRummy_CPA_starter_banus_100_728x90.gif"};

/*First Step*/
                        handler = new Handler();
                        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                            int i =0;
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(arr[i]).into(m_DealImage);
                                m_ToolTip.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                m_DealText.setText(dealText[i]);
                                i++;
                                if (i > arr.length - 1) {
                                    i = 0;
                                }
                                m_DealImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(View v) {
                                        //  Didn't know where to go
                                    }
                                });
                                handler.postDelayed(this, 6000);
                            }
                        };
                        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 6000);
```

Comment: Pass the required url to next activity using Intent extras. Here's how you can do that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265913/how-to-use-putextra-and-getextra-for-string-data

Answer (score 0):

Store image variable static and get clicked position from 
String[] arr = new String[]{..}.just pass that clicked position to another activity and using getIntent() to get position and firstactivity.arr[pos] then you will get url.

Example:
Activity 1:
public static String[] arr = new String[]{..}
Intent ->pass position(Clicked position)
Activity 2:
pos=getintent().getIntExtra(k,v);

now get url:
Activity1.arr[pos];

Comment: public static String[] arr = new String[]{
            "http://media.vcommission.com/brand/files/vcm/3012/Medlife_CPS_MLVC2_336X280.jpg",
   };

     Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(arr[0]).into(m_DealImage);
        m_DealImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class).putExtra("pos",1));
                                 

            }
        });

Comment: Activity2:imageView= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        int pos=getIntent().getIntExtra("pos",1);

        Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(MainActivity.arr[pos]).into(imageView);