# How can i declare all the brand's id globally and pass it as a parameter in http request using shared preference?

Tags: java, android, json, api

I need to pass the brand id values of my json response as a parameter to http request using shared preference.I also need to store the brand id values in my main Activity and retreive it in my AddVehicle activity  Please help me.Can i use arraylist? If yes, Then say me how? The id should check with the corresponding name and it should be displayed on my 2nd activity(AddVehicle)
Currently i have passed only one brand detail in my main Activity,but instead i need to pass all the id dynamically under one common variable?

My API response

```
{
  "status": 1,
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 1,----> brand id
      "name": "AUDI",
      "code": "AUDI",
      "image": "",
      "status": "1",
      "created_at": "2016-09-27 00:07:38",
      "updated_at": "2016-09-27 00:07:38"
    },
    {
      "id": 2-----> brand id
      "name": "Bravian Motor Works",
      "code": "BMW",
      "image": "",
      "status": "1",
      "created_at": "2016-09-27 00:07:58",
      "updated_at": "2016-09-27 00:07:58"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,---->brand id
      "name": "AB Volvo",
      "code": "VOLVO",
      "image": "",
      "status": "1",
      "created_at": "2016-09-27 00:08:36",
      "updated_at": "2016-09-27 00:08:36"
    },
    {
      "id": 4,-----> brand id
      "name": "Ford Motor Company",
      "code": "FORD",
      "image": "",
      "status": "1",
      "created_at": "2016-09-27 00:11:51",
      "updated_at": "2016-09-27 00:11:51"
    },
    {
      "id": 5,-----> brand id
      "name": "Maruti Suzuki",
      "code": "Maruti",
      "image": "",
      "status": "1",
      "created_at": "2016-09-27 00:12:14",
      "updated_at": "2016-09-27 00:12:14"
    }
  ],
  "msg": "success",
  "info": "data list"
}
```

MainActivity

```
package com.example.addvehicle;

import android.content.Intent;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.EditText;

import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.Action;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.AppIndex;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.Thing;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.JSONArray;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;


import static com.example.addvehicle.R.string.brand;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    ArrayList<String> brandListArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> modelListArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    Button addVehicleBtn;
    EditText AddVehicle_Regno, kmscovered;
    RadioButton petrol, Diesel, fullyloaded, Basicmodel;
    TextView textView8, textViewkms;
    Spinner AddspinnerMake, AddspinnerModel, AddspinnerYear;
    private static String url = "http://garage.kaptastech.mobi/api/5k/master/vehicle";
    private String[] values;
    ArrayList<String> brandListId;
    ArrayList<String> modelListId;

    String brandid;
    String modelId;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> addVehiclelist;

    String jsonStr;
    String Regno, fuelType, Brand, Year, Model, variant;
    /**
     * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
     * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
     */
    private GoogleApiClient client;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        brandListArray = new ArrayList<String>();
        brandListId = new ArrayList<String>();
        modelListArray = new ArrayList<String>();
        modelListId = new ArrayList<String>();


        addVehiclelist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        petrol = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.petrol);
        Diesel = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.diesel);
        fullyloaded = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.fullyLoaded);
        Basicmodel = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.basicmodel);
        addVehicleBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addVehicleBtn);
        AddVehicle_Regno = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.AddVehicle_Regno);
        kmscovered = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.kmsCovered);
        textView8 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView8);
        textViewkms = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewkms);
        AddspinnerMake = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.AddspinnerMake);
        AddspinnerModel = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.AddspinnerModel);
        AddspinnerYear = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.AddspinnerYear);



        new Getbrands().execute();

        petrol.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {

                if (petrol.isChecked()) {
                    fuelType = petrol.getText().toString();
                }
            }
        });

        Diesel.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {

                if (Diesel.isChecked()) {
                    fuelType = Diesel.getText().toString();
                }
            }
        });
        AddspinnerMake.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                Brand = AddspinnerMake.getSelectedItem().toString();


                if (position > 0) {
                    brandid = brandListId.get(position).toString();


                    //**Get Model execute api//
                    new Getmodels().execute();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        });
        AddspinnerYear.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                Year = AddspinnerYear.getSelectedItem().toString();

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        });
        AddspinnerModel.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                Model = AddspinnerModel.getSelectedItem().toString();

                if (position > 0) {
                    modelId = modelListId.get(position).toString();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        });
        Basicmodel.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {

                if (Basicmodel.isChecked()) {
                    variant = Basicmodel.getText().toString();
                }
            }
        });

        fullyloaded.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {

                if (fullyloaded.isChecked()) {
                    variant = fullyloaded.getText().toString();
                }
            }
        });



        addVehicleBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Regno = AddVehicle_Regno.getText().toString();
                new GetVehicle().execute();


                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddVehicle.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
    }

    /**
     * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
     * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
     */
    public Action getIndexApiAction() {
        Thing object = new Thing.Builder()
                .setName("Main Page") // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
                // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated URL is correct.
                .setUrl(Uri.parse("http://[ENTER-YOUR-URL-HERE]"))
                .build();
        return new Action.Builder(Action.TYPE_VIEW)
                .setObject(object)
                .setActionStatus(Action.STATUS_TYPE_COMPLETED)
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client.connect();
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.start(client, getIndexApiAction());
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.end(client, getIndexApiAction());
        client.disconnect();
    }

    private class GetVehicle extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://garage.kaptastech.mobi/api/5k/master/vehicle");

            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(7);
            nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user_id","5"));
            nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("registration_no", Regno));
            nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("brand","5"));
            nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("model", "4"));
            nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("type", "2"));
            nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("variant", "2"));
            nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("year", Year));

            try {
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                // writing error to Log
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            // Making HTTP Request
            try {
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);


                // writing response to log
                Log.d("Response from url:", response.toString());
                jsonStr = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                /*HttpConnection ht = new HttpConnection();
                ht.getVehicle();*/
                JSONObject object = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                JSONArray Vehicle = object.getJSONArray("data");
                for (int i = 0; i < Vehicle.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject c = Vehicle.getJSONObject(i);
                    String Regno = c.getString("registration_no");
                    String brand = c.getString("brand");
                    String model = c.getString("model");
                    String fueltype = c.getString("type");
                    String variant = c.getString("variant");
                    HashMap<String, String> Vl = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    Vl.put("registration_no", Regno);
                    Vl.put("brand", brand);
                    Vl.put("model", model);
                    Vl.put("type", fueltype);
                    Vl.put("variant:", variant);
                    addVehiclelist.add(Vl);
                    values = new String[]{
                            "Registration No:" + Regno,
                            "Brand:" + brand,
                            "Model:" + model,
                            "Type:" + fueltype,
                            "Variant:" + variant,
                    };
                }


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        }
    }

    private class Getbrands extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://garage.kaptastech.mobi/api/5k/master/brand");

            try {
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);


                // writing response to log
                Log.d("Response from url:", response.toString());
                jsonStr = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                HttpConnection ht = new HttpConnection();
                ht.getbrand();
                JSONObject object = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                JSONArray brandArray = object.getJSONArray("data");

                brandListArray.clear();
                brandListId.clear();
                brandListArray.add("Select Brand");
                brandListId.add("0");
                for (int i = 0; i < brandArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject gb = brandArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    brandListArray.add(gb.getString("name"));
                    brandListId.add(gb.getString("id"));
                    String[] brandStringArray = new String[brandListArray.size()];
                    brandStringArray = brandListArray.toArray(brandStringArray);
                    for (int i1 = 0; i1 < brandStringArray.length; i1++) {
                        Log.d("String is", (String) brandStringArray[i1]);
                    }

                }


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, brandListArray);
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            AddspinnerMake.setAdapter(adapter);


        }
    }

    private class Getmodels extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://garage.kaptastech.mobi/api/5k/master/models/" + brandid);

            try {
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);


                // writing response to log
                Log.d("Response from url:", response.toString());
                jsonStr = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                HttpConnection ht = new HttpConnection();
                ht.getmodel();
                JSONObject object = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                JSONArray modelArray = object.getJSONArray("data");

                modelListArray.clear();
                modelListId.clear();
                modelListArray.add("Select Model");
                modelListId.add("0");
                for (int i = 0; i < modelArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject gm = modelArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    modelListArray.add(gm.getString("name"));
                    modelListId.add(gm.getString("id"));
                    String[] modelStringArray = new String[modelListArray.size()];
                    modelStringArray = modelListArray.toArray(modelStringArray);
                    for (int i2 = 0; i2 < modelStringArray.length; i2++) {
                        Log.d("String is", (String) modelStringArray[i2]);
                    }
                }


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, modelListArray);
            AddspinnerModel.setAdapter(adapter);


        }
    }
}
```

And i need to retreive it on my AddVehicle Activity

AddVehicleActivity

```
package com.example.addvehicle;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class AddVehicle extends AppCompatActivity {
    ListView addVehicleListView;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> VehicleList;
    ArrayList<String> brandListId;
    private String[] values;
    private static String urlString = "http://garage.kaptastech.mobi/api/5k/users/vehicle";
    private String TAG = AddVehicle.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);
        brandListId = new ArrayList<String>();
        VehicleList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        addVehicleListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.addVehicleListView);
        new GetVehicle().execute();
    }

    private class GetVehicle extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {


        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

            HttpConnection ht = new HttpConnection();
            String response = ht.getVehicle();
            {
                try {

                    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpGet get = new HttpGet("http://garage.kaptastech.mobi/api/5k/users/vehicle");
                    JSONObject Object = new JSONObject(response);
                    JSONArray Vehicle = Object.getJSONArray("data");
                    for (int i = 0; i < Vehicle.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = Vehicle.getJSONObject(i);
                        String Regno = c.getString("registration_no");
                        String brand = c.getString("brand_id");
                        String model = c.getString("model_id");
                        String fueltype = c.getString("type");
                        String variant = c.getString("variant");
                        HashMap<String, String> Vl = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        Vl.put("registration_no", Regno);
                        Vl.put("brand_id", brand);
                        Vl.put("model_id", model);
                        Vl.put("type", fueltype);
                        Vl.put("variant:" , variant);
                        VehicleList.add(Vl);
                        values = new String[]{
                                "Registration No:" + Regno,
                                "Brand Id:" + brand,
                                "Model Id:" + model,
                                "Type:" + fueltype,
                                "Variant:" + variant,
                        };
                    }
                } catch (final Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return null;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(AddVehicle.this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);
            //ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(AddVehicle.this, VehicleList, R.layout.activity_list, new String[]{"brand_id", "model_id", "registration_no", "type", "variant"}, new int[]{R.id.AddspinnerMake, R.id.AddspinnerModel, R.id.AddVehicle_Regno, R.id.fullyLoaded, R.id.basicmodel});
            addVehicleListView.setAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: First off, this is too much code. Please reduce it to the necessary elements. Second you can add values to your `Intent` using `intent.putExtra("key", value)`. This can be anything you want, so in your case maybe a map with id-name. Alternatively you could just dump the entire JSON in the intent en handle it in the vehicle class

Comment: Maybe this topic is useful for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139134/how-to-send-an-object-from-one-android-activity-to-another-using-intents

Comment: @RoelStrolenberg so, how can i get the global variable from it,As i said right, I need to pass all the 5 brand's ID dynamically which is declared under one common variable,as  a parameter to the HTTP request using post method,I thinks so it will be showing the error "Expression expected":

Comment: You can get it using `getIntent()` as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265913/how-to-use-putextra-and-getextra-for-string-data