# How to send data from fragment to another activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent

I need to send data from Fragment to another activity

I am using this code in my LoadsFragment under HomeActivity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(activity, LoadActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("loadsPosition",position);
activity.startActivity(intent);
```

in another activity(LoadActivity) to receive data

```
Intent intent=getIntent();    
String loadsPosition = intent.getStringExtra("loadsPosition");
```

but intent has no Extras

see the screenshots below

[image: From fragment sending intent][image: in second activity getting extras][image]

Comment: question is unclear

Comment: `getActivity()` and `activity.startActivity(intent)` both are same?

Comment: Yes, both are same

Comment: please read the following post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265913/how-to-use-putextra-and-getextra-for-string-data

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use putExtra() and getExtra() for string data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265913/how-to-use-putextra-and-getextra-for-string-data)

Comment: plese see my updated question with screenshoots

Comment: Put a [mcve] of all the code, not screenshots or out of context snippets

Comment: @DhanuK can you please post manifest block of LoadActivity

Comment: Change intent.hasExtras("meta_data") to intent.hasExtras(""loadsPosition") in LoadActivity. Looks like you are checking a wrong key

Comment: You can use `EventBus` https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus for these works.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> but intent has no Extras

Your screenshot says it does...

Your second screenshot shows `processIntent(Bundle bundle)`, but the third shows `processIntent(Intent intent)`, so you should clarify which isn't working. But both Bundles are not null.

[Fragments have their own `startActivity` method.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#startActivity(android.content.Intent)) You only need the parent Activity to create the Intent

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), LoadActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("loadsPosition",position);
startActivity(intent);
```

Most importantly, your position is an integer, but you're trying to get it as a string, therefore the string will be null

```
Intent intent=getIntent();    
int loadsPosition = intent.getIntExtra("loadsPosition", -1);
```

The Intent should not be null, and it should have a Bundle. If this integer comes back as -1, then the default here has been returned, and you should debug some more with a smaller example

Answer (score 3):

Try using interfaces.

Any fragment that should pass data back to its HomeActivity should declare an interface to handle and pass the data. Then make sure your HomeActivity implements those interfaces. For example:

In your fragment, declare the interface...

```
public interface OnDataPass {
    public void onDataPass(String data);
}
```

Then, connect the HomeActivity class' implementation of the interface to the fragment in the onAttach method, like so:

OnDataPass dataPasser;

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    dataPasser = (OnDataPass) context;
}
```

Within your fragment, when you need to handle the passing of data, just call it on the dataPasser object:

```
public void passData(String data) {
    dataPasser.onDataPass(data);
}
```

Finally, in your HomeActivity which implements OnDataPass...

```
@Override
public void onDataPass(String data) {
    Log.d("LOG","hello " + data);
}
```

Comment: do you understood what question is? i am trying to send data to a activity, that is started in fragment.

Answer (score 1):

In fragment Use

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity, LoadActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("loadsPosition",position);
activity.startActivity(intent);
```

in LoadActivity

```
String loadsPosition = getIntent().getStringExtra("loadsPosition");
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try like this and see if you're getting the extras:

1. When you create the intent:
   `Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoadActivity.class);`
2. But most probably you are processing getExtras() instead of the intent itself.

   `try{
       processIntent(getIntent());
   }catch(JSONException e){
   ...`

Comment: `new Intent(this,` doesn't work from a Fragment class

Answer (score 0):

You did not attach extras to your intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(activity.this, LoadActivity.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putInt("loadsPosition",pos);
intent.putExtras(bundle);
activity.startActivity(intent);
```

or:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(activity.this, LoadActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("loadsPosition",pos);
activity.startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Local Broad Cast Receiver or Interface to pass data from fragment to activity.

Answer (score -1):

Actvity 1 Fragment :

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), SecondActivity.class);
 intent.putExtra("message", data); 
 startActivity(intent);
```

In second activity fragment retrieve in this manner

```
 SecondActivity activity = (SecondActivity) getActivity();
 String data= activity.getIntent().getExtras().getString("message");
```

Comment: please see screenshots

Answer (score -1):

> You can also directly take intent extras data of activity in fragment.
>   If you are having data in your activity intent.Use below code in your
>   fragment:

```
Intent intent = getIntent().getStringExtra("position");
```