# Arraylist Pass from fragment to activity

Tags: android

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), loadactivity.class);
intent.putExtra("Arraylist", imagearraylist);
startActivity(intent)
```

Comment: do you have array list of string or object?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send data from fragment to another activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46954409/how-to-send-data-from-fragment-to-another-activity)

Comment: That is object arraylist

Comment: Possible Dublicate Please Check The Links Below [Passing ArrayList From Activity To Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39867847/android-passing-arraylistmodel-to-fragment-from-activity)

Comment: I am not passing String data... I want to send arraylist

Comment: I want to pass from fragment to activity that is for passing arraylist to fragment @VaithiyaNathan

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putParcelableArrayListExtra(java.lang.String,%20java.util.ArrayList%3C?%20extends%20android.os.Parcelable%3E)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15133121/pass-arraylist-implements-parcelable-to-activity

Comment: you should use a parcelable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this will help you!
Paste the following code in your activity.

```
ArrayList<Object> imagearraylist = (ArrayList<Object>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("Arraylist");
```

Reference: [How to pass ArrayList<CustomeObject> from one activity to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21250339/how-to-pass-arraylistcustomeobject-from-one-activity-to-another)

Comment: bro its activity to activity not for fragment to activity @Hay

Answer (score 0):

Use Interface Like Mentioned In Link

[Passing Data Between Fragments to Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14440095/8812246)

Or You Can Simply Use `Public static ArrayList<String> imagearraylist;`

(Passing Huge Arraylist Through Intent May Leads To Crash)

Answer (score 0):

For this, you have to use interface

```
    public interface arrayInterface {    
        public void onSetArray(ArrayList<T>);         
    }
```

Implement this interface in your activity

```
public class YrActivity extends Activity implements arrayInterface.OnFragmentInteractionListener {
       private ArrayList<T> allData;
    @override
    public void arrayInterface(ArrayList<T> data) {
      allData = data;
    }
    }
```

Then you have to send the data with listner

```
arrayInterface listener = (arrayInterface) activity;
listener.onSetArray(allData)
```

And its done