# How do I fetch specific data from a page and display that data in a TextView

Tags: android

I'm trying to make an Android app that logs into my University's student webpage in the background and gathers specific data like class timings for my next class and then displays it in a `TextView` in the App. How do I achieve this?

Comment: You need to learn JSON and API calling for that.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Please provide the response, without watching we can't help you

Answer (score 1):

There are so many ways to share data from one activity to another.Here I described two of them.

***1. Declare static variable because***

> Static variables are initialized only once, at the start of the
>   execution. These variables will be initialized first, before the
>   initialization of any instance variables. A single copy to be shared
>   by all instances of the class. A static variable can be accessed
>   directly by the class name and doesn't need any object.

For Example:
**In First Activity**

```
EditText edit;
static String sample;
//Code
edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_txt);
sample=edit.getText().toString();
```

**In Second Activity**

```
TextView txt;

txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);
txt.setText(First_Activity.sample);
```

***2.Second Method is using putExtra() and getExtra()***

**In First Activity**

```
    EditText edit;
    String sample;
    //Code
    edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_txt);
    sample=edit.getText().toString();
    Intent i=new Intent(this,Second_Activity.class);
    i.putExtra("text",sample);
```

**In second Activity get these values:**

```
 TextView txt;
    String test;
    txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);
    Intent i=getIntent().getExtra();
    test=i.getString("text");
    txt.setText(test);
```

> Read these for more information

https://www.androidhive.info/2011/08/how-to-switch-between-activities-in-android/

[How to use putExtra() and getExtra() for string data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265913/how-to-use-putextra-and-getextra-for-string-data)

Hope this one will be helpful.