# Calling a method immediately after starting intent in android?

Tags: java, android

**Starting Intent then calling Method?**
In the two classes, the second one has a StartIntent. Right now it simply starts the intent to the first class. I am wanting to know if it is possible from that same onClickListener to essentially StartIntent for the first class as usual, but then immediately call the defaultMap() method within it.

Sometimes I want to simply start the intent normally, and other times I want to start the intent and then call that method. 1) therefore, I can't just make so that OnCreate of the first class it calls defaultMap, because i don't always want to call it. But also 2) I don't want to JUST call the defaultMap() class. I need to call the full class so that it runs through the onCreate functions THEN goes to the defaultMap

**FIRST CLASS USED**

```
public class Daily_Schedule extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_daily__schedule);

    ......
    .......
    ......

}

public void defaultMap(){
    ......
    .......
    ......
}
```

**SECOND CLASS USED**

```
 public class InRouteDisplay extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_in_route_display);

    home.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent myIntent = new Intent(InRouteDisplay.this, DailySchedule.class);
            InRouteDisplay.this.startActivity(myIntent);

        }
    });
    .....
    ....
    .....

}
```

Comment: Could you please be more clear with 1) and 2)
I think you can call defaultMap() inside onCreate in Daily_Schedule class!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following: Two ways: 1) Using putExtra()  --------  2) Using SharedPreferences

1)

Demo4.class:-----------

```
public class Demo4 extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button b;
private final String CALL_DEFAULT_MAP = "call_default_map";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_daily__schedule);


    if(getIntent() != null) {//1
        if(getIntent().getStringExtra(CALL_DEFAULT_MAP) != null) {
            if (getIntent().getStringExtra(CALL_DEFAULT_MAP).equals("true")) {
                defaultMap();
            }
        }
    }


    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent myIntent = new Intent(Demo4.this, Demo5.class);
            finish();
            startActivity(myIntent);

        }
    });

}

public void defaultMap() {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"defaultMap()---called",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}


}
```

Demo5.class------

```
public class Demo5 extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button home;
private final String CALL_DEFAULT_MAP = "call_default_map";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_in_route_display);


    home = (Button) findViewById(R.id.home);

    home.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            Intent myIntent = new Intent(Demo5.this, Demo4.class);
            myIntent.putExtra(CALL_DEFAULT_MAP,"true");//1
            finish();
            startActivity(myIntent);

        }
    });

}


}
```

2)

Demo4.class---------

```
public class Demo4 extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button b;
private final String CALL_DEFAULT_MAP = "call_default_map";
private SharedPreferences p;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_daily__schedule);

    p = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("p_key",
            0);//2


    if(p != null){//2
        if(p.getBoolean(CALL_DEFAULT_MAP , false)){
            defaultMap();
        }
    }


    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent myIntent = new Intent(Demo4.this, Demo5.class);
            finish();
            startActivity(myIntent);

        }
    });

}

public void defaultMap() {
    setBoolean(CALL_DEFAULT_MAP , false);//2
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"defaultMap()---called",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

public void setBoolean(String Name, boolean value)
{
    if(p != null){
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = p.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(Name, value);
        editor.apply();
    }
}

}
```

Demo5.class:----------------

```
public class Demo5 extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button home;
private final String CALL_DEFAULT_MAP = "call_default_map";
private SharedPreferences p;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_in_route_display);

    p = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("p_key",
            0);

    home = (Button) findViewById(R.id.home);

    home.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            setBoolean(CALL_DEFAULT_MAP , true);//2
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(Demo5.this, Demo4.class);
                            finish();
            startActivity(myIntent);

        }
    });

}

public void setBoolean(String Name, boolean value)
{
    if(p != null){
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = p.edit();
    editor.putBoolean(Name, value);
    editor.apply();
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

No.  The sending class doesn't get an instance of the Activity to call it on.  What you can do is set a parameter in the intent, USE_DEFAULT_MAP to 1.  The activity you launch can look for that variable, and use that to know that it should call defaultMap.

Answer (score 0):

Use if statement inside the Daily_Schedule activity and check the extra whether they are set or null. Use `getIntent()` method. [check the answer of this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233873/how-do-i-get-extra-data-from-intent-on-android)

From InRouteDisplay activity pass the intent data using putextra before calling `InRouteDisplay.this.startActivity(myIntent);`

Use this link to how to putextra data to the intent
[Use this link's answer to know how to putextra data to the intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265913/how-to-use-putextra-and-getextra-for-string-data)