# NullPointerException when getting image path in PhotoEditor SDK (Android)

Tags: java, android, react-native, photoeditorsdk

I'm using Photo Editor SDK for Android application with React Native. Application crashes when either photo is chosen from the gallery or taken with camera. Tested on Android 8.1, 5, and 6. We are using v5 of the PESDK library and targetSdkVersion 27.
In MainActivity we have

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == PESDK_EDITOR_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        String resultPath = data.getStringExtra(ImgLyIntent.RESULT_IMAGE_PATH);
        //...
    }
}
```

It crashes on the data.getStringExtra() line. Here is the stacktrace:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=12345678, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {com.***/com.***.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.ClassLoader java.lang.Class.getClassLoader()' on a null object reference
   at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4440)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4484)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap19(Unknown Source)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1743)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6753)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:482)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)

Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.ClassLoader java.lang.Class.getClassLoader()' on a null object reference
   at ly.img.android.sdk.models.state.manager.SettingsList.<init>(SettingsList.java:93)
   at ly.img.android.sdk.models.state.manager.SettingsList$1.createFromParcel(SettingsList.java:44)
   at ly.img.android.sdk.models.state.manager.SettingsList$1.createFromParcel(SettingsList.java:41)
   at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2851)
   at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2745)
   at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:3114)
   at android.os.BaseBundle.initializeFromParcelLocked(BaseBundle.java:273)
   at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:226)
   at android.os.BaseBundle.getString(BaseBundle.java:1118)
   at android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(Intent.java:7139)
   at com.***.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:46)
   at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7312)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4436)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4484)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap19(Unknown Source)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1743)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6753)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:482)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

NPE is thrown from the library. I have simply followed the tutorial, I don't know what am I doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265913/how-to-use-putextra-and-getextra-for-string-data/5265952#5265952

Comment: Activity which is returning result does have putextra with ImgLyIntent.RESULT_IMAGE_PATH?just make sure also post that activities code if you can.