# How to get added items list from cart on next activity

Tags: android

I'm student and developing online food booking app . I'm getting food list from api and displaying in list.On + button I'm able to add item in cart but I want on cart image click , I move on new activity and there I want to  get all added items list and display in list view.1) 1st code snippet it my adapter class where I have + button to increase the item count .2) 2nd Code is my model class 3) 3rd code snippet is my fragment code where on button click i want to move on order class.

I advance thanks.Please help me.

```
 static ArrayList<AddedPizzaInfo> bookmarker_array = new ArrayList<AddedPizzaInfo>();
 holder.increase.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                count++;
                holder.integer_number.setText(String.valueOf(count));
                total_value = holder.integer_number.getText().toString();if(actionListener!=null)actionListener.onItemTap(holder.itemCopyIV);
                AddedPizzaInfo bookmarkerPojo = new AddedPizzaInfo();
                bookmarkerPojo.SetName(c.getName());
                bookmarker_array.add( bookmarkerPojo);// adding item but
=======
public class AddedPizzaInfo {
private String name = "";
public AddedPizzaInfo() {}
public AddedPizzaInfo( String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public void SetName(String name){this.name = name;}
public String GetName(String name){
    return this.name;
}
```

}

====`textCartItemCount.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent startSecondActivityIntent = new Intent(Veg_Pizza_Activity.this, Order_Summary.class);
                startSecondActivityIntent.putExtra("items", Parcels.wrap(bookmarker_array));
                startActivity(startSecondActivityIntent);
                (Veg_Pizza_Activity.this).overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
            }
        });`

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Use API for cart items based on user id best for you and get all added cart items

Comment: U will do it by making putExtra into intent look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265913/how-to-use-putextra-and-getextra-for-string-data

Comment: AddedPizzaInfo bookmarkerPojo = new AddedPizzaInfo();
                    bookmarkerPojo.SetName(c.getName());
                    bookmarker_array.add( bookmarkerPojo);
                  Adding item by this way.

Comment: Please help ,me. I have stucked in code.

Comment: Kindly provide me solution .

Answer (score 0):

Make your Item class implement @Parcel (using this library https://github.com/johncarl81/parceler)

then, on the first activity:

```
Intent startSecondActivityIntent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
startSecondActivityIntent.putExtra("items", Parcels.wrap(yourListOnItems));
startActivity(startSecondActivityIntent);
```

on the second acitivty:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
    listOfItems = Parcels.unwrap(bundle.getParcelable("items"));
}
```

Alternatively to using Parceler library you could implement [Parceleable natively](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable) but will take too much time and generate too much boilerplate code.

**EDIT:**

AddedPizzaInfo.class:

```
@Parcel
public class AddedPizzaInfo{
    //code whatever

    //add empty constructer, required by parceler
    public AddedPizzaInfo(){} 

    //rest of the code
}
```

build.gradle:

```
...

dependencies {

   ///other dependencies
    implementation 'org.parceler:parceler-api:1.1.9'
    annotationProcessor 'org.parceler:parceler:1.1.9'
}
```

and then run the code I first added when you want to send the objects you your second activity.

Comment: holder.increase.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {@Overridepublic void onClick(View v) {count++; holder.integer_number.setText(String.valueOf(count)); total_value = holder.integer_number.getText().toString();
                    if(actionListener!=null)actionListener.onItemTap(holder.itemCopyIV);AddedPizzaInfo bookmarkerPojo = new AddedPizzaInfo();bookmarkerPojo.SetName(c.getName());bookmarker_array.add( bookmarkerPojo);});

Comment: adding  by this way . I have shared my code above sir, now please share where I'm doing mistake.

Comment: holder.increase.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {@Overridepublic void onClick(View v) {count++; holder.integer_number.setText(String.valueOf(count)); total_value = holder.integer_number.getText().toString(); if(actionListener!=null)actionListener.onItemTap(holder.itemCopyIV);AddedPizzaInfo bookmarkerPojo = new AddedPizzaInfo();bookmarkerPojo.SetName(c.getName());bookmarker_array.add( bookmarkerPojo);});

Comment: Edited my answer. The code you provided is very unclear.

Comment: "listOfItems" what is it? will you plz tell me sir?

Comment: it's and ArrayList<AddedPizzaInfo>

Comment: Unable to find generated Parcelable class for com.pizza_App.AddedPizzaInfo, verify that your class is configured properly and that the Parcelable .Getting this error.

Comment: Check here https://github.com/johncarl81/parceler an example of a class implementing Parcel. Check if your is the same

Comment: all is same sir

Comment: Okay Sir @ Tiago Ormelas

Answer (score 0):

To send list data from one activity use the following code sample

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, TargetActivity.class);
        intent.putStringArrayListExtra("your_list",listOfData);
        startActivity(intent);
```

To retrieve the list in TargetActivity use

```
if(getIntent()!=null){
    your_array_list = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("your_list");
}
```