# onActivityResult return null data

Tags: android, kotlin

I've just been coding in kotlin for a while. I've got some problems.

It always return null data in after I click item in second activity.

**first activity**

```
btnClick.setOnClickListener { v ->
        val intent = Intent(applicationContext, NumberPickerActivity::class.java)
        startActivityForResult(intent, 777)
    }



 override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    try {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (requestCode == 777 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            val result = data?.getStringExtra("picked_product").toString()
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, e.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }

}
```

**second activity**

```
override fun onItemClick(item: Product) {
         val intent = Intent()
         intent.putExtra("picked_product", item.price)
         setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent)
         finish()
}
```

Comment: Is `item.price` an Integer or String?

Comment: item.price is Integer

Comment: Does it work if you get the extra from the intent instead:
Intent intent = getIntent();
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
extras.getString("picked_product");

similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265913/how-to-use-putextra-and-getextra-for-string-data

Comment: thank, but it didn't work for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are expecting an `Int`, do this instead:

```
val result = data?.getIntExtra("picked_product", 0) //0 will be used in case no value in data and result is now Integer.
```

Answer (score 0):

The extra you put in your intent is an Integer (`item.price`). But you are trying to retrive a String `data?.getStringExtra("picked_product")`.

Sinc the intent does not contain a String at the key `"picked_product"`, it returns `null`.

You should try to get an Int extra :

```
val result = data?.getIntExtra("picked_product")
```

---

Nothing to do with your problem but it's useless to do

```
data?.getStringExtra("picked_product").toString()
```

Since it return you a String the use of `toString()` is useless