# how to import ID from one activity to another?

Tags: xml, android-studio, kotlin

I am unable to pass data from (EditText) one activity to another activity.

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/inputText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/eg_raaz"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="@string/name"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.059"
        android:autofillHints="" />
```

ActivityMain.kt

```
package com.example.bday

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }

    fun createCard(view: View) {
        var name=inputText.editableText.toString(); //here error occurs
    }
}
```

I'd used EditText Id as "inputText" but I am unable to access it from ActivityMain.kt .

Comment: Use `putExtra` and `getExtra` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265913/how-to-use-putextra-and-getextra-for-string-data

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to correctly reference your `inputText` layout.
You can do it by adding a synthetic import on top of your `MainActivity` class:

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
```

Anyway, since the synthetic import method is deprecated you may wanna use one of two methods:

1. The `findViewById` method:

```
fun createCard(view: View) {
    var name=findViewById<EditText>(R.id.inputText).editableText.toString();
    ...
}
```

2. The view binding method from the Android Jetpack (newest and suggested):

```
private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        val view = binding.root
        setContentView(view)
    }

    fun createCard(view: View) {
        var name=binding.inputText.editableText.toString();
        ...
    }
}
```

For more information about view binding and how to set it up correctly see [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding)

Once you have a valid reference to the `inputText` field you can pass its data by using the `putExtra` method:

```
fun createCard(view: View) {
    var name=binding.inputText.editableText.toString();

    val intent = Intent(this, NextActivity::class.java)
    intent.putExtra("name", name)

    startActivity(intent)
}
```

You can then retrieve the name retrieve it in `NextActivity` with the `getStringExtra` method:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val name = intent.getStringExtra("name") ?: ""
}
```

Comment: @user:13211263 @luca_999 unresolved reference kotlinx is showing when I am importing `import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*`

Comment: kotlinx synthetic is deprecated, use view binding or findViewById (easiest) and it will work

Comment: @MerthanErdem I was adapting to the user's approach. Anyway, I've extended my answer with a longer explanation. Thank you for the tip.