# How can i use a variable from an Activity to another Activty?

Tags: java, android-studio, variables

In my `MainActivity` i have a score variable,
`int score = 0;`

however  i have another activity which is the `DisplayScore` activity (which displays the score) `txtFinalScore.setText("Score: " + score);`

how can i use that same variable form my `MainActivity` to my `DisplayScore` activity so that i can display the score?

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood well, here's how you should do it.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int score = 0; // the main activity thing

        int displayScore = score; // the thing to use the same value as score

        System.out.println("Score : " + displayScore); // to simulate the setText
   }
}
```

Comment: This code has no activities in it. OP is referring to the concept of `Activity` in an Android app, not just to simple local variables.

Comment: I see, then how do we do it ?

Comment: Sorry, I'd post a counter-answer if I could. But I've done very little mobile dev, and it was awhile ago, so I'll let someone with more recent Android experience answer this.

Comment: Alright! It's all good.

Comment: Appreciate the help! But i asked something different, which has been solved now anyways, i wanted to use a variable from one Activity to another i Android Studio, i did this by using `getExra()` and `PutExtra()` methods.

Comment: Oh, sorry if it didn't help but i'm glad you got your answer!

Answer (score 0):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265913/how-to-use-putextra-and-getextra-for-string-data) explains perfectly how to use `putExtra()` and `getExtra()` methods for the **Intent** in Android, because I think that's what you need.

Also, if you find this difficult, you can store the score value into a sharedPreference and retrieve it from another activity. You can see the docs [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences).